# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre las funciones de inicio de jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre?:

```
$(function(){

});
```

y

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

});
```

Sé que esperan a que los componentes estén cargados, pero quisiera saber ¿por qué se escriben de manera diferente?.

*Pregunta similar de SO en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662778/what-is-the-difference-between-these-jquery-ready-functions*

Comment: Hola José, ¿tu pregunta está inspirada [en esta del sitio en inglés](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2662778/4574)? Si es así deberías mencionarlo y añadir un enlace al final de tu pregunta.

Comment: Entendido. no tanto inspirada ya que la duda me surgió por que estoy desarrollando un proyecto con JQuery, pero igualmente pondré el link ya que es muy similar.

Comment: Sorry, what?! no comprendo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Oficialmente [no hay ninguna diferencia](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3):

> Esta función se comporta igual que `$(document).ready()`, en el
>   sentido de que debería usarse para envolver otras operaciones `$()` de
>   tu página que dependan de que el DOM ya esté listo.

Puedes verlo en [las fuentes](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.js):

```
rootjQuery = jQuery(document);

...

} else if ( jQuery.isFunction( selector ) ) {
    return rootjQuery.ready( selector );
}
```

<s>Sin embargo, técnicamente sí hay una diferencia que podría ser útil según las circunstancias: `$(function()` no se ejecutará si jQuery no se ha cargado correctamente, mientras que `$(document).ready` sí lo hará</s>

**Actualización:** Tal como se menciona en los comentarios `$(document).ready` tampoco se ejecutará si jQuery no está cargado. Para conseguir un efecto similar ([pero no idéntico](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3698200/4574)) sin jQuery se puede usar `window.onload`.

*Esta respuesta es una traducción de la original en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2662783/4574 (la última frase no estaba en el original)*

Comment: Ya que traducimos, traducimos todo... xDDDD.  *Si que hay una diferencia, `$(function(){})` es menos leible (al menos en mi cerebro)* by [`Rosdi Kasim`](http://stackoverflow.com/users/193634/rosdi-kasim)

Comment: ¿Podrías aclarar la última frase: "_`$(function()` no se ejecutará si jQuery no se ha cargado correctamente, mientras que `$(document).ready` sí lo hará_"? Si jQuery no se ha cargado correctamente, ninguna de las dos debería ejecutarse porque `$` no estaría definido y se recibiría un error en ambos casos

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Claro que sí, te lo explico de una forma muy sencilla: metí la pata. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Viendo que la pregunta data del año 2015. Hoy día hay una gran diferencia:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

});
```

**ha sido declarado obsoleto en jQuery3** y muy probablemente desaparecerá en jQuery4.

Por lo tanto, para mantener el código actualizado, se recomienda empezar a usar desde ya:

```
$(function(){

});
```

en todo nuestro código.

Este cambio viene explicado con toda claridad en la API de jQuery:

> jQuery offers several ways to attach a function that will run when the
>   DOM is ready. All of the following syntaxes are equivalent:
>
> ```
> $( handler )
> $( document ).ready( handler )
> $( "document" ).ready( handler )
> $( "img" ).ready( handler )
> $().ready( handler )
> ```
>
> As of jQuery 3.0, only the first syntax is recommended; the other
>   syntaxes still work but are deprecated. This is because the selection
>   has no bearing on the behavior of the .ready() method, which is
>   inefficient and can lead to incorrect assumptions about the method's
>   behavior. For example, the third syntax works with "document" which
>   selects nothing. The fourth syntax waits for the document to be ready
>   but implies (incorrectly) that it waits for images to become ready.
>
> <sub>Ver: [`.ready()` en la API de jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)</sub>
>
> ---
>
> JQuery ofrece varias maneras de adjuntar una función que se ejecutará
>   cuando el DOM esté listo. Todas las sintaxis siguientes son
>   equivalentes:
>
> ```
> $( handler )
> $( document ).ready( handler )
> $( "document" ).ready( handler )
> $( "img" ).ready( handler )
> $().ready( handler )
> ```
>
> **A partir de jQuery 3.0, sólo se recomienda la primera sintaxis; las otras sintaxis siguen funcionando pero están obsoletas**. Esto se debe
>   a que la selección no tiene relación con el comportamiento del método
>   `.ready()`, que es ineficiente y puede conducir a suposiciones
>   incorrectas sobre el comportamiento del método. Por ejemplo, la
>   tercera sintaxis funciona con "documento" que no selecciona nada. La
>   cuarta sintaxis espera que el documento esté listo, pero implica
>   (incorrectamente) que espera que las imágenes estén listas.

---

**En conclusión:** la forma recomendada desde jQuery3 es:

```
$(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

---

Se puede consultar también las siguientes preguntas:

- [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre `window.onload` y `$(document).ready()`?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/51961/29967)
- [jQuery 3 declaró `document.ready` obsoleto ¿hay cambios también para `window.load`?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/92628/29967)

Answer (score 2):

Según la documentación:

> **jQuery( callback ):** Enlaza una función a ser ejecutada cuando el DOM haya finalizado su carga. El comportamiento es como `$().ready()` y deberá ser usado para encapsular otras operaciones que dependan del que el DOM esté cargado.

Mientras que:

> **.ready( handler ):** Especifica una función a ejecutar cuando el DOM está completamente cargado.

Si se ejecuta después de cargado el DOM, su función (normalmente anónima) será ejecutada de inmediato.

#### Conclusión:

Ambos métodos son sinónimos. El uso de uno u otro es cuestión de que lo prefieras. Yo por ejemplo me gusta mucho el primero pues como lo mencionan es el uso corto.

#### Recomendación:

Lo recomendable es que utilices el alias `jQuery` para obtener el comportamiento deseado siempre en tus plugins o componentes (no importa el método que emplees), ejemplos:

### Método 1:

```
jQuery(function( $ ) {
    // Tú código usando aquí el alias «$».
});
```

### Método 2:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  // Código usando el símbolo «$» (como comúnmente) aquí.
});
```

#### Fuentes

- [jQuery() | jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/)
- [.ready() | jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Answer (score 0):

Esto también es equivalente:

```
    $(document).on('ready',function() { 

    });
```

Personalmente recomiendo usar por defecto el método `on`, y para el caso del metodo `ready` recomiendo no usarlo, y en su reemplazo mantener el orden de la ejecución de los scripts/funciones cuando sepas que los recursos (elementos/variables, app.js) ya existen en el contexto actual, y/o ejecutar esos mismos script/funciones en callbacks.