# No me reconoce el id de un input pasado desde php con ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Este es el código `PHP` que realiza una consulta y que genera el `HTML`:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['ef'])){
    $sentenci = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM familia");
    $sentenci->execute();
    $numb = $sentenci->rowCount();
    if($numb==0){
    echo "<h5>No hay ninguna</h5>";
    }
    else{
        $cadena = "<form><table>";
        $cadena .= "<tr><th>Ciclo</th><th>Seleccionar</th></tr>";
        while($fila=$sentenci->fetch()){
            $cadena .= "<tr><td>".$fila['familia']."</td><td><input type='checkbox' name='elfam' value=\"".$fila['idfam']."\"></td></tr>";

        }
        $cadena .= "<tr><td colspan'2'><input type='button' value='enviar' id=\"ef\" class=\"btn btn-primary\"></td></tr></table><form>";
        echo $cadena;
    }
}
```

Sin embargo, en el evento click de `#ef` del HTML generado en [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) no muestra la alerta.

```
$("#ef").on('click',function(){
  alert("eliminado");
});
```

**Ajax**

```
$.post("./php/consultas.php",{ef:""},function(data){
    $("#famel").text("");
    $("#famel").append(data);
});
```

Comment: donde pones la fuincion onClick? dentro de document.ready o tras tu response en la peticion ajax?

Comment: dentro de document.ready

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La forma que usa `$("#ef").on('click',function(){...}` funcionará para los elementos existentes en el `DOM`, mas  **no para los nuevos elementos** que vienen por medio de `Ajax`

Para solucionar este detalle de agregar elementos dinámica mente al `DOM` la forma correcta de emplear [el método on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) es

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#ef', function(event) {
      alert("Eliminado");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

supongo que tienes algo asi

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#ef").on('click',function(){
        alert("eliminado");
    });
});
```

el problema es que cuando el documento cargo no existia $("#ef")

lo que tienes que hacer es agregar tu funcion on click despues de llamar al ajax

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "tu_php.php",
  data: { datos:"datos" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    $("#algundiv").html( msg );
    $("#ef").on('click',function(){
            alert("eliminado");
        });
  });
```

si lo hiciste con $.post:

```
$.post("tu_php.php", { datos:"datos" }).done(function( msg) {
        $("#algundiv").html( msg );
        $("#ef").on('click',function(){
                alert("eliminado");
        });
});
```

Comment: mi ajax lo he hecho con $.post y el done para que sirve?

Comment: `$.post` es una abreviatura para `$.ajax({ method: 'POST', ...`. El `done()` es la función que se ejecuta una vez que la petición ajax se haya completado.

Comment: done indica que se hace cuando ya obtuviste respuesta

Answer (score 1):

No tienes por qué escapar los identificadores HTML con `\`. Puedes escribir así:

```
<td colspan'2'><input type='button' value='enviar' id='ef' class='btn btn-primary'></td>
```

Te pongo este ejemplo, el cual funciona. Lo puedes probar pulsando en ejecutar y luego en el botón.

La verificación del Document Ready la he usado simplemente con `$(function()`, ya que, la forma en la que lo verificamos habitualmente  ha pasado desde jQuery 3 al estado *deprecated* y desaparecerá en jQuery 4, por eso se recomienda desde ahora usar `function` como aparece en el ejemplo. [Ver esta respuesta al final](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/51961/29967).

```html
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $("#ef").click( function()
       {
         alert('botón funciona');
       }
  );
});
</script>

<tr>
<td colspan'2'><input type='button' value='enviar' id='ef' class='btn btn-primary'></td>
</tr>
```