# Cual es la diferencia entre usar `window.addEventListener` y `window.document.addEventListener`

Tags: javascript

Cual es la diferencia entre usar `window.addEventListener` y `window.document.addEventListener`

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(k){

if(k.altKey) {
alert("Solamente window.addEventListener: Tecla [ALT] PRESIONADA");
}
else {
alert("Solamente window.addEventListener: Tecla [ALT], NO PRESIONADA");
}

}, false);


window.document.addEventListener("keydown", function(k){

if(k.altKey) {
alert("Con window.document.addEventListener: Tecla [ALT] PRESIONADA");
}
else {
alert("Con window.document.addEventListener: Tecla [ALT], NO PRESIONADA");
}

}, false);
```

```html
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No se incluye comentario alguno sobre lo buscado/investigado ni sobre el código incluido.

Comment: En esencia la diferencia está explicada en la respuesta a la pregunta: **[¿Cuál es la diferencia entre window.onload y $(document).ready()?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/51961/29967)**. La respuesta es detallada y muestra un código de ejemplo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para este caso no hay ninguna diferencia. Pero quizas te sean mas utiles estos links: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp y https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp

En el te explican la diferencia de `window` y `document`:

#### Document

Es el componente raiz de la aplicacion, y los demas nodos incluyendo `window` son `hijos` de este.
Por lo que al asignarle un evento al document va a capturarlo siempre.

#### Window

Es un componente que representa a la ventana, en el ejemplo tambien capturaria el evento pues es la unica ventana que existe en la aplicacion.

Pero puede comportarse de forma distinta si se tienen varias ventanas, lo cual se puede lograr con el tag `iframe`, el cual crea un objeto ventana para cada iframe que tengas, en este caso solo capturaria el evento de la ventana que tengas seleccionada.

Para mas informacion https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp.

Tambien aclarar que `window` es una variable global, que tiene como miembro document, que es el nodo raiz

Comment: gracias ! voy a leer mas :)