# Por que mi eventListener(Click) se ejecuta al recargar la pagina y no al hacer click?

Tags: javascript, html5

Esto deberia ser algo sencillo pero estoy aprendiendo de esto... El asunto es que ese ejecuta toda la funcion al recargar la pagina y no al hacer click en el boton

```js
document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", alert("Aqui hay algo nuevo"),false);

function clickeando(){
 alert("Aqui hay algo!");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Practicas Javascript</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

</head>
<body>
 <p class="clase1">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi voluptates amet blanditiis, quis asperiores voluptas fuga libero obcaecati nostrum odit labore commodi, delectus natus vel nam fugit repellat quae autem!

 </p> 
 <button id="btn1">Clickeando Ando!</button>


<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

En ningún momento le dices a tu botón que ejecute la función clickeando cuando el evento on.click del mismo ocurra.

Tu código puede quedar así, recordando que siempre es importante encerrar el código que atañe a los elementos del DOM dentro de `DOMContentLoaded`.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

  var btn = document.getElementById("btn1");
  btn.onclick = function() {
    alert('Aquí hay algo')
  };

});
```

```html
<p class="clase1">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi voluptates amet blanditiis, quis asperiores voluptas fuga libero obcaecati nostrum odit labore commodi, delectus natus vel nam fugit repellat quae autem!

</p>
<button id="btn1">Clickeando Ando!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Otra buena opción seria colocar esta parte al inicio de tu código:

```js
window.onload = function() {
 var mb = document.getElementById("btnUno");
 mb.addEventListener("click", clickSomethingMatch);
```

Fijate que te he cambiado el nombre de la id. No te recomiendo que uses numeros en variables ya que te puede dar conflicto, usa el cameltoe.

Comment: No es adecuado llamar `window.onload` en este caso, ya que estamos trabajando con elementos del DOM, por lo cual lo mejor de cara al rendimiento sería llamar `DOMContentLoaded`. Para comprender la diferencia, [ver esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/51946/29967)

Answer (score 0):

Estas ejecutando el alert directamente en vez de pasarle la referencia de una funcion.

Esto:

```
document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", alert("Aqui hay algo nuevo"),false);
```

Es igual a esto:

```
var resultadoAlert = alert("Aqui hay algo nuevo");
document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", resultadoAlert ,false);
```

Lo que provoca que se envie muestre el alert y se envie como parametro el resultado de la funcion `alert()` que es `undefined`.

Enviale la referencia de una funcion para lograr lo que quieres. Aqui las 2 maneras de hacerlo:

```js
// enviandole la referencia de la funcion clickeando
document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", clickeando,false);

// enviando la referencia de una funcion anomina al evento.
document.getElementById("btn2").addEventListener("click", function(){
  alert("Clickeando algo nuevo!");
},false);

function clickeando(){
 alert("Aqui hay algo!");
}
```

```html
 <p class="clase1">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi voluptates amet blanditiis, quis asperiores voluptas fuga libero obcaecati nostrum odit labore commodi, delectus natus vel nam fugit repellat quae autem!

 </p> 
 <button id="btn1">Clickeando algo!</button>
   <button id="btn2">Clickeando algo nuevo!</button>
```