# ¿Cómo simplificar condiciones en PHP?

Tags: php

lo que pasa es que tengo 2 condiciones, las cuales muestran el mismo resultado. ¿Hay alguna manera de usar una sola condición?
Agradecería su respuesta, gracias

```
 if ($getMesg == "Contacto") {


echo  '</br><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" id="ws">Facebook</a>'; }


 if ($getMesg == "Precios") {


echo  '</br><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" id="ws">Facebook</a>'; }
```

Comment: con el operador OR: `if ($getMesg == "Contacto" || $getMesg == "Precios") { ... }`

Comment: @Cris223511.dev Muchas gracias por el consejo, al fin ya pude :)

Comment: Otra forma: `if(in_array($getMesg, ['Contacto', 'Precios'])) { ... }` Si es necesario, puedes poner más elementos dentro del array.

Comment: @aeportugal Gracias por el consejo!

Comment: También puedes usar [*operador ternario*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php), algo así: `echo (in_array($getMesg, ['Contacto', 'Precios'])) ? '</br><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" id="ws">Facebook</a>' : '';`

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias!

Comment: Otra cosa, tus etiquetas `br` están mal escritas así: `</br>` la forma correcta de escribir los elementos vacíos debería ser: **`<br />`** Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/136203/29967) y también [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/228043/29967) para más detalles. El problema es que si escribes `</br>`, aunque haga el trabajo, ese contenido no pasaría una validación XML / XHTML.