# Como recargar una pagina con JS

Tags: javascript, web

en esta ocasion me gustaria saber cuales son las maneras de recarga una pagina web con Javascript.

```
window.location.reload(); 
/*o este*/
document.location.reload();
```

Estos 2 funciones me permiten recarga la pagina. Cuales son sus diferencias?

En mi caso, me gustaría que cuando el usuario presione f5 o recarga la pagina con el botón "reload" del navegador lo devuelva pero al inicio de la pagina y no se mantenga en la sección donde se hizo scroll. Seria recargar la misma pagina (index.html).

Hace sus acciones pero de manera infinita.

Comment: La diferencia está explicada [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/51961/29967) (la imagen es muy ilustrativa para entenderlo). `document` es el documento actual, que se conoce también como DOM, y `window` es la ventana actual. El `document` es un nodo inferior al `window`, porque el `document` es una de las partes del `window`. Por ejemplo cuando tienes una página web como las habituales y en ella tienes un `iframe`, tanto el contenido de tu página como el `iframe` son nodos que están en el `window`.

Comment: Buen dia Cedano, gracias por contestar. Ok y si tengo una pagina  que esta llena de imágenes (imágenes me refieron a propiedades como background-image en css o la etiqueta img en html) debería trabajar con window.reload para la página index.html?  Pregunto por que las funciones que mencion arriba tiene 2 paramatros que son true o false.

Comment: Cuando uso false, este me recargue pero desde el cache del navegador, por el contrario si uso true me recarga el window pero desde el servidor.

Comment: Tengo una pagina estática en html, sin muchas animaciones. Entonces seria conveniente que cuando presione f5 o se actualize me llevara al inicio y que cargue las animacion con js desde 0. En vez de que se queda en la misma posicion del scroll

Comment: Observa bien la organización jerárquica en [la imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjGtr.png). Todo lo que es `form`, imágenes (`img`), hojas de estilo (CSS), etc, dependen de `document`. Lo que me dices sobre caché de navegador o caché del servidor no lo entiendo. Si tienes caché en alguna parte y quieres recargar con cosas nuevas quizá tengas que implementar una limpieza de caché junto con el código de recarga.