# ¿Cómo acceder al contenido del tag <object> en HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, svg

Intento acceder al contenido de un tag `<object>` que carga un archivo. En lo especifico, deseo acceder al id de algunos de sus elementos y he probado a hacerlo con CSS y con JavaScript, pero nada parece funcionar. No logro acceder a los id o clases de los elementos que se cargan desde el archivo.

> El problema persiste a pesar del tipo de archivo utilizado, he probado con archivos html y svg.

---

Etiqueta `<object>`:

```
<object id="obj" data="test.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

Archivo SVG:

```
<svg width="680" height="370" style="border-radius:30px" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 179.91 97.897" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <path id="test" d="m9.2398 47.875 22.601 6.4716 69.367 0.0251c0.68665 2.51e-4 1.4406-0.39775 1.4217-1.5326l-3.7e-4 -25.974-74.08-17.624z" fill="#333" opacity=".5" style="mix-blend-mode:color-dodge"/>
</svg>
```

JavaScript con el que intento acceder a los id:

```
<!-- jQuery full con ajax -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    $(window).on('load', function(){ 
        console.log( document.getElementById('test') )
        // Devuelve: null
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log( document.getElementById('test') )
        // Devuelve: null
        
        console.log( $('#obj').contentDocument )
        // Devuelve: undefined
    });
</script>
```

CSS tampoco detecta el id:

```
#obj {color: red !important} /* No funciona */
#test {fill: red} /* No funciona */
```

> La etiqueta `<embed src="..." \>` se comporta de la misma manera

Comment: Para el color prueba a poner en el CSS `fill:red`

Comment: Ya lo intenté y no funciona. Nota que también intenté con un archivo html. El problema es que no consigo obtener el elemento usando el ID o la Clase.

Comment: Lo que quiero hacer es mucho más complejo que asignar un color, necesito que tanto javascript como css puedan acceder a esos id para animar un archivo svg.

Comment: ¿[esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798745/how-to-get-html-elements-from-an-object-tag) soluciona tu duda?

Comment: Cargar el svg desde javascript te serviría ? algo asi: https://jsfiddle.net/r2svaLk6/

Comment: Es un post muy viejo y está desactualizado, probé varias de sus soluciones sin resultado.

Comment: @Israel lo probaré.

Comment: @Israel ese JavaScript no carga el archivo.

Comment: @ArielMontes lo he probado en mi servidor antes de publicarlo y no he tenido problema en cargarlo. La url que estás usando del archivo SVG está en local o es una url externa ?

Comment: En un code pen me funciona. Veré si logro adaptarlo a la lógica que necesito implementar. Aun así dejaré esta pregunta abierta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siempre y cuando el `SVG` este hosteado en el mismo dominio que la página, podes hacerlo así:

- Primero busca el `object` en el documento
- Luego accede al `contentDocument` del `object`
- Finalmente busca por `id` el elemento dentro del `contentDocument`

#### Ejemplo:

```
$(function() {
    let element = document.getElementById('obj').contentDocument.getElementById('test');
    console.log(element);
});
```

---

**PD:** te recomiendo leer [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre window.onload y $(document).ready()?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/51946/16597)

Comment: Gracias, lo voy a probar. Y para acceder al ID con CSS ¿sería posible o tendría que aplicar los estilos con js?

Comment: Funciona de maravillas. Ahora queda solo mi duda sobre el CSS.

Comment: Si queres modificar el `SVG` solo usando `CSS`, el `SVG` tendría que estar incrustado en el página, es decir, no deberías usar `object`

Comment: No quiero usar solo CSS, pero con js no se como crear animaciones en CSS, no se siquiera si sea posible.

Comment: Es una buena pregunta que podes publicar, asi la comunidad puede responderte. La respuesta corta es, si, si se puede. [Mas info aca](https://css-tricks.com/animating-svg-css/)