# Error: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un trozo de código que es de un sitio web que está en Internet y estoy copiando ese mismo código para pegarlo en otro sitio web en localhost, pero al hacer esto me esta saliendo un error bastante extraño que no logro solucionar.

**Error que me lanza:** *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null*

[image: Error que me lanza por consola]

### Qué quiero lograr

Lo que quiero lograr es que cuando pulse o haga clic en uno de los 6 botones, por ejemplo en el botón **P** de párrafo, este me escriba `<p></p>` automáticamente en el textarea como ya lo he hecho otras veces en otra página web.

### Código

```js
var cuerpo = document.querySelector('#body');
var parrafo = document.querySelector('#p');
var strong = document.querySelector('#strong');
var b = document.querySelector('#b');
var a = document.querySelector('#a');
var h2 = document.querySelector('#h2');
var h3 = document.querySelector('#h3');

// Parrafo
parrafo.addEventListener('click', () => {
    var endPos = cuerpo.selectionEnd; // obtiene la posicion del cursor
    var del = cuerpo.value.substring(endPos,cuerpo.value.length); // obtiene valor desde la posicion del cursor hasta el final del valor
    cuerpo.value = cuerpo.value.replace(del,""); // elimina el valor obtenido en del
    cuerpo.value += "<p>"; // añade un h2
    var po = cuerpo.value.length; // obtiene la nueva posicion a poner del cursor ( la posicion anteniro en este caso+ 4 )
    cuerpo.value += "</p>"; // añade del finas del h2
    cuerpo.value += del; // añade el valor eliminado
    cuerpo.focus(); // poner en focus el input
    cuerpo.setSelectionRange(po,po); // pone el cursor dentro de h2
});

// Etiqueta Strong
strong.addEventListener('click', () => {
    var endPos = cuerpo.selectionEnd; // obtiene la posicion del cursor
    var del = cuerpo.value.substring(endPos,cuerpo.value.length); // obtiene valor desde la posicion del cursor hasta el final del valor
    cuerpo.value = cuerpo.value.replace(del,""); // elimina el valor obtenido en del
    cuerpo.value += "<strong>"; // añade un h2
    var po = cuerpo.value.length; // obtiene la nueva posicion a poner del cursor ( la posicion anteniro en este caso+ 4 )
    cuerpo.value += "</strong>"; // añade del finas del h2
    cuerpo.value += del; // añade el valor eliminado
    cuerpo.focus(); // poner en focus el input
    cuerpo.setSelectionRange(po,po); // pone el cursor dentro de h2
});

// Etiqueta <b>
b.addEventListener('click', () => {
    var endPos = cuerpo.selectionEnd; // obtiene la posicion del cursor
    var del = cuerpo.value.substring(endPos,cuerpo.value.length); // obtiene valor desde la posicion del cursor hasta el final del valor
    cuerpo.value = cuerpo.value.replace(del,""); // elimina el valor obtenido en del
    cuerpo.value += "<b>"; // añade un h2
    var po = cuerpo.value.length; // obtiene la nueva posicion a poner del cursor ( la posicion anteniro en este caso+ 4 )
    cuerpo.value += "</b>"; // añade del finas del h2
    cuerpo.value += del; // añade el valor eliminado
    cuerpo.focus(); // poner en focus el input
    cuerpo.setSelectionRange(po,po); // pone el cursor dentro de h2
});

// Enlace
a.addEventListener('click', () => {
    var endPos = cuerpo.selectionEnd; // obtiene la posicion del cursor
    var del = cuerpo.value.substring(endPos,cuerpo.value.length); // obtiene valor desde la posicion del cursor hasta el final del valor
    cuerpo.value = cuerpo.value.replace(del,""); // elimina el valor obtenido en del
    cuerpo.value += "<a href='' class='blue-text'>"; // añade un h2
    var po = cuerpo.value.length; // obtiene la nueva posicion a poner del cursor ( la posicion anteniro en este caso+ 4 )
    cuerpo.value += "</a>"; // añade del finas del h2
    cuerpo.value += del; // añade el valor eliminado
    cuerpo.focus(); // poner en focus el input
    cuerpo.setSelectionRange(po,po); // pone el cursor dentro de h2
});

// H2
h2.addEventListener('click', () => {
    var endPos = cuerpo.selectionEnd; // obtiene la posicion del cursor
    var del = cuerpo.value.substring(endPos,cuerpo.value.length); // obtiene valor desde la posicion del cursor hasta el final del valor
    cuerpo.value = cuerpo.value.replace(del,""); // elimina el valor obtenido en del
    cuerpo.value += "<h2 class='flow-text'>"; // añade un h2
    var po = cuerpo.value.length; // obtiene la nueva posicion a poner del cursor ( la posicion anteniro en este caso+ 4 )
    cuerpo.value += "</h2>"; // añade del finas del h2
    cuerpo.value += del; // añade el valor eliminado
    cuerpo.focus(); // poner en focus el input
    cuerpo.setSelectionRange(po,po); // pone el cursor dentro de h2
});

// H3
h3.addEventListener('click', () => {
    var endPos = cuerpo.selectionEnd; // obtiene la posicion del cursor
    var del = cuerpo.value.substring(endPos,cuerpo.value.length); // obtiene valor desde la posicion del cursor hasta el final del valor
    cuerpo.value = cuerpo.value.replace(del,""); // elimina el valor obtenido en del
    cuerpo.value += "<h3 class='flow-text'>"; // añade un h2
    var po = cuerpo.value.length; // obtiene la nueva posicion a poner del cursor ( la posicion anteniro en este caso+ 4 )
    cuerpo.value += "</h3>"; // añade del finas del h2
    cuerpo.value += del; // añade el valor eliminado
    cuerpo.focus(); // poner en focus el input
    cuerpo.setSelectionRange(po,po); // pone el cursor dentro de h2
});
```

```html
<!-- BBCode -->
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <button id="p" type="button" class="waves-effect pink darken-2 btn">
                                p
                        </button>

                        <button id="strong" type="button" class="waves-effect pink darken-2 btn">
                            strong
                        </button>

                        <button id="b" type="button" class="waves-effect pink darken-2 btn">
                            b
                        </button>

                        <button id="a" type="button" class="waves-effect pink darken-2 btn">
                            a
                        </button>

                        <button id="h2" type="button" class="waves-effect pink darken-2 btn">
                            h2
                        </button>

                        <button id="h3" type="button" class="waves-effect pink darken-2 btn">
                            h3
                        </button>
                    </div>
```

Cuando hago clic sobre uno de los botones, este no escribe nada en el textarea como debería de escribir.

Comment: Tu problema está en el elemento `cuerpo`, no existe ningún elemento con `id="body"`, si quieres seleccionar el elemento `body` como tal tienes que hacer algo así: `querySelector('body')`

Comment: El elemento `id="body"` es el id del textarea, es solo que no lo mostré en el código debido a que solo mostré los botones para escribir las etiquetas de html

Comment: Se requiere siempre un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable en las preguntas. Yo probé el código con lo que compartiste en la pregunta y había error porque no encontraba el elemento `cuerpo`. Si había un `textarea` con ese id debiste compartirlo inicialmente en la pregunta. Otra cosa, la respuesta aceptada no es del todo correcta, para este caso deberías escuchar la carga del DOM, no la carga de window que es un elemento de jerarquía superior. El código no queda optimizado así. Para más detalles lee [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/51946/29967) y la respuesta dada.

Comment: Para evitar confusiones, dado que la pregunta referida es sobre jQuery, aclaro que en vez de `window.onload` para este caso  debes escuchar a `DOMContentLoaded`, que es el evento que indica que el DOM ha sido cargado. [Revisa los ejemplos en la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event#examples).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extraño la verdad, se me ocurren dos alternativas con la información proporcionada:

- Que estes ejecutando el script en el head del html, y por lo tanto el DOM no se haya renderizado y el componente no exista. Por lo que la solución sería mover el script al final del html. Si quieres mantenerlo al principio, puedes hacer que se llame con el evento de carga. Ejemplo:

  ```
  window.onload = function() {
    ...tu codigo...
  };
  ```
- Dado que buscar componentes por id, usar la alternativa
  `document.getElementById()`, aunque el resultado debería ser el mismo.

Comment: Tenias razón, estaba cargando el script en el head y eso era lo que generaba el problema. ya lo solucione. Muchas gracias

Comment: Por alguna razón que desconozco acabo de subir los cambios a producción y en producción me esta saliendo el mismo error que anteriormente y en **localhost** todo marcha bien. Porque será ?

Comment: Que raro, pero prueba con la función window.onload a ver.

Comment: No me funciona ni siquiera en localhost y no he tocado el código del localhot, no se que esta pasando.

Comment: Otra cosa, no estoy utilizando Jquery, la funcion window.onload no es de jquery cierto ?

Comment: cierto, window.onload es js nativo

Comment: Ya logre solucionarlo nuevamente, olvide que había eliminado el botón del parra, lo ciento ya funciona tanto en **Localhost** como **Producción**