# ¿Cómo cargar una función al terminar de cargar mi página?

Tags: javascript, html, eventos

Tengo una ventana modal y se carga al darle click a éste enlace

```
<a class="btn btn-success editAddressCompanieModal" empresa_id = "{{ $data['companies']->empresa_id }}" >Dirección</a>
```

Y se ejecuta este script

```
$(document).on('click', '.editAddressCompanieModal', function(){
var user_id = $(this).attr('empresa_id');
$.ajax({
    url: "{{url('admin/companies/editaddress')}}",
    type: "POST",
    data: '&empresa_id='+user_id,
    success: function (data) {
        $('.editContent').html(data);
        $('#editAddressModal').modal('show');
    },
    dataType: 'html'
});
```

Pero también quiero que al cargar la página se despliegue la ventan o la misma función. Ya intente copiando el código y cambiando el click por onload y el on por el addEventListener pero no me abre la ventana cuando termina de cargar la página. ¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo recomendable es que uses el método `ready` encapsules tu ajax en una función, y la llames luego en el método mencionado, podría quedar de esta forma:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    
    llamar_ajax(); // al cargar el documento, se ejecutará dicha función

    function llamar_ajax(){  // encapsular función ajax
    var user_id = $("#mi_selector").attr('empresa_id'); // debes obtener el selector directo
       $.ajax({
       url: "{{url('admin/companies/editaddress')}}",
       type: "POST",
       data: '&empresa_id='+user_id,
       success: function (data) {
          $('.editContent').html(data);
          $('#editAddressModal').modal('show');
       },
       dataType: 'html'
    });
    } // fin función
});
```

Comment: Orales, si funciono. Muchas gracias crack!!!

Comment: @Hugo, `jQuery.ready` esta deprecado. Mas [info acá](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/51961/16597)