# Cual es el nombre de la superficie en donde se renderizan los elementos html?

Tags: html, css

Bien, al hacer una pagina web lo unico que hacemos es *renderizar* elementos `html` (elementos que graficamente son *cuadrados* o tambien denominados *cajas*) sobre una superficie que brinda el navegador, pues bien cual es el nombre de esta superficie ?. Para dar un ejemplo practico de mi duda, aqui va la siguiente pagina ...

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Muy buen fichaje el de Memphis Depay xd
    </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
html
{
    background-color    : #0f0;
    border              : 10px solid #f00;
}

body
{
    background-color : #fff;
    border : 10px  solid #92f;  
}
```

Bien en este caso vemos una pagina en donde el `html` contiene al `body`, teniendo esto en cuenta, la pregunta seria: *cual es el nombre de la superficie en donde se renderizaron estos elementos ?* ( superficie que tiene un color de fondo igual al de la etiqueta `html`, lo cual supongo que se debe a que el navegador le asigna el color del tag `html` en caso de que lo tenga, en caso de que no, el del body y en caso de que este tampoco tenga, blanco)

Soy muy novato con el desarrollo frontend, si tiene alguna aclaratoria o correccion, seria de mucha ayuda :).

Comment: las etiquetas `html` indican el inicio y fin de tu página si tu le aplicas un color al fondo al HTMl se verá reflejado en todos sus elementos hijos, por ultimo todo los elementos HTML pertenecen al DOM

Comment: En los navegadores el elemento con jerarquía superior es Window, del cual dependen otros como `document`  (conocido también como DOM), están los `iframes`  y otros. Revisa el gráfico al final de [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/51961/29967), en él verás la jerarquía completa.

Comment: No es claro si te refieres al [*Canvas*](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/intro.html#the-canvas) o al *Viewport*.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te refieres al DOM `Modelo de Objetos del Documento` que es donde se ejecutan los elementos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El DOM seria la estructura de tu sitio, lugar donde se ejecutan las etiquetas del mismo. CSS y JS leen tu estructura, DOM y actúan sobre el, así es como CSS o JS es capaz de identificar los divs ya sea por clase o atributo.

Puedes leer un poco más de el DOOM aquí https://lenguajejs.com/javascript/dom/que-es/

El html básicamente encapsula toda tu estructura, pero no se trabajan estilos sobre el html si no sobre el body y sus elementos, ya que es ahí donde se ejecutan los elementos que se mostraran en pantalla.