# ¿ Cual es la forma mas optima de detectar que el documento fue cargado completamente con JS puro?

Tags: javascript

No puedo detectar cuando la pagina se cargo completamente. Primero trate con este codigo y funciona correctamente:

```
let stateCheck = setInterval( ()=>{
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
          clearInterval(stateCheck);
          console.log('Funciona')
    }
}, 100);
```

Pero cuando no uso el set interval no me funciona, ¿ por que ?:

```
if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
     console.log('Funciona')
}
```

Comment: No funciona porque, al momento de ejecutar ese bloque de código, la página aún no ha cargado en su totalidad, mientras que con `setInterval()` analizas el estado cada 100 milisegundos. Lo más adecuado es detectar la carga por un evento, como el que te sugieren en la respuesta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes utilizar un EventListener de javascript puro:

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    console.log("La página ha terminado de cargar");
  });
</script>
```

Básicamente, realiza algún bloque de código que determines cuando todos los recursos de la página se han cargado.
¡Saludos!

Comment: Excelente, gracias, debo esperar 8 minutos para marcar como correcta bro :)

Comment: !un placer ayudar! :D

Comment: Conviene diferenciar entre `window` (toda la ventana) y `document` (el DOM). El código de esta respuesta escucha la carga de la ventana completa. Si te interesa escuchar la carga del DOM, lo propio es usar [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event). Para más detalles y entender la diferencia entre `window` y `document`  [ver esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/51961/29967).

Comment: Es importante tenerlo en cuenta, sobre todo por motivos de rendimiento. Acabo de probar el snippet de la respuesta referida anteriormente y **hay una diferencia de 10 segundos** entre la carga del `DOM` y la carga de `window`. Por tanto, un código que escuche el `window`, cuando debería escuchar el `DOM` no está **optimizado**. Se debe esperar la carga del `window` únicamente si necesitas trabajar con elementos que están en él dentro de tu bloque de código (imágenes, iframes, etc).

Comment: Amigo puedes puntear la pregunta como util por favor, nunca he preguntado, es para obtener la medalla de estudiante

Comment: @A.Cedano, de acuerdo a la pregunta, `readyState == 'complete'` es equivalente al evento `load`, [referencia](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState). Por otra parte, no sé si haya diferencia entre al analizar la carga completa entre ventana y documento, sería cuestión de probar.

Comment: @Triby, yo me refiero a esta respuesta, donde se escucha a `window`. Y en cuanto a si hay diferencia, la hay, sobre todo si `window` carga un iframe. [Si revisas el snippet de la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/51946/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-window-onload-y-document-ready/51961#51961) podrás ver a la derecha el momento en que cada uno notifica que está completo.

Comment: @A.Cedano, acabo de hacer unas pruebas y `readyState == 'complete'` se dispara casi al mismo tiempo que `load` de la ventana, ambos esperan a que se hayan cargado todos los recursos del documento, que es el comportamiento esperado por OP, al menos eso entiendo con _"el documento fue cargado completamente"_.