# Por que el metodo document.getElementsByTagName() de HTML no funciona como espero?

Tags: javascript, array, metodos

- Buenas, resulta que estoy haciendo unas prácticas con `HTML` y el método `document.getElementsByTagName` no funciona como espero. Se supone que este metodo retorna una `HTMLColletion`, la cual a pesar de no ser un arreglo, es iterable como uno, sin embargo cuando trato de iterar el `HTMLCollection` retornado, me da resultados inesperados, veamos:

Código:

> ```
>  'use strict';
>     let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body'); // por qué no funciona como se espera el getElementByTagName
>     console.log(body)
> ```

-Este codigo retorna lo que se podría esperar ...

Resultado:

> `HTMLCollection { length: 0 }`

Sin embargo, si lo trato de iterar pasa lo siguiente ...

Codigo:

```
 'use strict'; let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]; 
 console.log(body)
```

Resultado:

> `null`

- Por otro lado, si iteramos usando el método `.item(0)`, en lugar de retornar `null` retorna `undefined`. Por otro lado, en la consola, todo funciona como espero. ¿A qué se debe este comportamiento?

Comment: A mi me funciona bien, no soy capaz de reproducir tu error. Míralo en [este enlace](https://jsfiddle.net/5gctqv7f/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seguramente tengas tu código javascript en tu código HTML **antes** de la etiqueta `body`:

```html
<html>
 ...
<script> // tu código </script>
...
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Los navegadores interpretan el HTML de manera secuencial: en este caso se carga el Javascript, se ejecuta y **después** se procesa el `body`:

```html
<script>
   console.log("buscando antes", document.getElementById("despues"));
</script>

<div id="despues"></div>

<script>
   console.log("buscando después", document.getElementById("despues"));
</script>
```

Soluciones:

- Añadir el código después del body.
- Hacer que el código se ejecute cuando la página termine de ejecutarse:

```javascript
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  // tu código
});
```

- Si tu código Javascript está en un fichero externo (es decir, en lugar de añadir el código en el propio HTML estás usando el atributo `src`), puedes usar el atributo `defer` para indicar que la ejecución se realice después de procesar todo el HTML:

```
<script src="miFichero.js" defer></script>
```

Comment: Agrego adicionalmente que tambien podrias Incluir tu Codigo Al Final del cierre del body
</body>
asi se ejecutara el script al final..

Lo correcto seria esperar al Evento LOAD o OnLoad del body para ejecutarlo..

Otra opcion es crear una custom function y cargarla en el evento..

<body onLoad="customFunction()">
</body>

Pero esto ya casi no se usa

Comment: También puedes agregar `defer` al elemento `script` para que se ejecute luego de leer todo el HTML. `<script defer></script>`

Comment: @Mateo Correcto, lo añado a la lista de soluciones

Comment: Aunque quizá conviene hacer la diferencia entre la carga de `window` y la carga del `DOM`, no es lo mismo y puede que en algunos contextos baste con escuchar la carga del `DOM`. Revisar [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/51946/29967) puede ser interesante en ese sentido.