# Problema querySelectorAll() vacio

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo una funcion donde estoy usando querySelectorAll(); cuando la llamo por medio de un boton funciona perfectamente; pero si la ejecuto automaticamente me devuelve el array vacio.

Alguin me podria ayudar.

```js
function totalInputs() {
    console.log('Ejecutada');
    const foodSelections = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=number]");
    console.log(foodSelections);
}
totalInputs()
```

Comment: Parece que la función se ejecuta antes de que los elementos se hayan agregado al DOM. Prueba ejecutándola en el evento `onload`.

Comment: Hay se esta ejecutando la primera funcion, de donde estoy llamando totalInputs().

Comment: Posible duplicada de https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/560203/por-que-el-metodo-document-getelementsbytagname-de-html-no-funciona-como-esper/560206#560206

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Por que el metodo document.getElementsByTagName() de HTML no funciona como espero?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/560203/por-que-el-metodo-document-getelementsbytagname-de-html-no-funciona-como-esper). Ver también la pregunta: [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre window.onload y $(document).ready()?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/51946/29967).