# Ejecutar codigo de javaScript despues de cargar la pagina desde herramientas de desarrollador en chrome

Tags: javascript, dom, chrome

soy nuevo en este foro y en el tema de manipulación del DOM con javaScript de lo cual busco apoyo.

Estoy intentando hacer web scraping en una página web la cual tiene una tabla, dentro de un ifrmae llamado products, en cada fila de la tabla se encuentra el nombre del producto y al dar clic sobre el nombre del producto, en un recuadro a la derecha, aparece la descripción del producto (nombre, marca, precio, contenido).

Ya que no cuento con la opción de instalar algún lenguaje de programación y librerías para hacerlo, mi solución fue realizar esto por medio de los snippets de google Chrome para ejecutar código de javascript, pero al intentar correr un bucle for para recorrer cada elemento de la tabla, darle clic y obtener la información del recuadro derecho, el código se ejecuta sin esperar a que cargue la página con el siguiente producto, intente con la función setTimeOut pero el resultado fue el mismo

Mi código se vería más o menos así

```
//Obtener número de productos en el ifrmae
let nProductos = products.document.getElementByClassName("product").length
//Bucle for para recorrer cada producto
for (let i = 1; i<=nProductos; i++ {
   products.document.querySelector(elemento i).click()
   //cdigo para obtener datos del recuadro de información
   let información += datos del recuadro 
}
//Imprimir en consola los datos recabados
console.log(información)
```

El proble no es acceder a la información del inframe o del recuadro derecho, sino, hacer que al dar clic en un elemento del iframe el codigo espere a que se cargue la nueva información y seguir con el bucle

Comment: Puedes indicar cual es la página en cuestión ?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre window.onload y $(document).ready()?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/51946/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-window-onload-y-document-ready). Los elementos como `iframe` se encuentran en el `window`, por lo que deberías poner tu bloque de código dentro de `window.onload`

Comment: No se que tiene que ver `jQuery` en esta pregunta, como para que sea un duplicado de esa otra.