# jQuery 3 declaró document.ready obsoleto ¿hay cambios también para window.load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-3

En jQuery exist(ían) al menos cuatro funciones para manipular elementos del DOM cuando el mismo estuviese listo:

```
$( handler )
$( document ).ready( handler )
$( "document" ).ready( handler )
$( "img" ).ready( handler )
$().ready( handler )
```

De ellas quizá la más usada es la segunda:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

La cual ha sido declarada obsoleta a partir de jQuery 3.

Aunque actualmente nuestro código funciona, es posible que deje de hacerlo en jQuery 4. Por tanto, se recomienda reemplazar el código anterior por este:

```
$(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

La noticia de obsolescencia de `document.ready` se [encuentra aquí](https://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> A partir de jQuery 3.0, sólo se recomienda la primera sintaxis, o sea, `$(function() { ...    });` Las
>   otras sintaxis **siguen funcionando pero están obsoletas**. Esto se debe a
>   que la selección no tiene relación con el comportamiento del método
>   `.ready ()`, que es ineficiente y puede conducir a suposiciones
>   incorrectas sobre el comportamiento del método. Por ejemplo, la
>   tercera sintaxis funciona con "documento" que no selecciona nada. La
>   cuarta sintaxis espera que el documento esté listo, pero implica
>   (incorrectamente) que espera que las imágenes estén listas.

---

### La pregunta

Mi pregunta es con respecto al hermano mayor de `$( document ).ready(function() {`, es decir,  `$(window).load(function() {});`

**¿jQuery 3 también ha cambiado con respecto a `window.load`?**

Si ha cambiado, **¿cuál sería la forma de actualizar el código?**

---

> Pregunta relacionada: [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre window.onload y
>   $(document).ready()?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/51946/29967)

Comment: Muy buena pregunta "Dorothy" (Expresion del meme)..http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Z7-WHm3YTog/0.jpg

Comment: Según lo que tengo entendido, `$(document).ready(hdl)` es prácticamente un polyfill para `DOMContentLoaded`, así que para fines prácticos, es conveniente este último **por ser un estándar**. Respecto a `$(window).load(hdl)`, es lo mismo, como `.val()` es a `.value`. ([Referencia al código fuente](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/bd984f0ee2cf40107a669d80d92566b8625b1e6b/src/core/ready.js)

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Cuáles son las novedades y las ventajas de jQuery 3?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/51533/65)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No importa si es window, document, img o lo que sea, lo que se eliminó son los metodos **.load(), .unload(), y .error()**

> Cambios importantes: .load(), .unload(), and .error() eliminados
>
> Estos metodos son accesos directos a operaciones de eventos, pero tienen
>   verdaderas limitaciones con la API. El evento .load() genera un conflicto con > el metodo ajax.load(). El metodo .error() no puede ser usado con 
>   window.onerror por la manera en la que esta definida el metodo del DOM. Si 
>   se necesita vincular este tipo de eventos, usar el metodo on(), ej: cambiar 
>   $("img").load(fn) por $("img").on("load",fn).

En lugar de usar

```
$(window).load(function() {});
```

se usará

```
$(window).on("load", function (e) {});
```

Es importante usar `"load"` ya que el evento `"ready"` tambíen fué eliminado

> Cambios importantes: .on("ready", fn) eliminado
>
> jQuery ya no soporta el evento sintético "ready" que puede ser usado con las 
>   funciones del evento. Este evento era susceptible a errores y deprecado en 
>   jQuery 1.8 porque este solo llamaría al callback si este era vinculado antes 
>   de que el documento estuviera listo. Reemplazar cualquier uso con $(fn) en su > lugar, seguramente funcione.

Puedes checarlo en [Cambios en JQuery 3.0](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-load-unload-and-error-removed)

Comment: La respuesta despeja toda duda. Aceptaría si las notas estuviesen traducidas. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

La verdad es que no sé si habrá cambiado, pero lo que puedo comentar al respecto y compartir es la manera en la que yo ejecuto mis funciones cuando quiero utilizar el window.load, recordemos que esto es una asignación, por lo que solo puedes ejecutar un función a la vez, por el contrario, si agregas este pequeño trozo de código en tu js o en varios js's que quieras cargar con funciones puedes hacer algo asi:

```
if (document.addEventListener){
    window.addEventListener('load',la_funcion_que_sea,false);
} else {
    window.attachEvent('onload',la_funcion_que_sea);
}
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda. Saludos!
La información mas completa lo puedes encontrar en este post: 
http://codexexempla.org/articulos/2007/lanzar_funciones.php