# ¿Cómo pasar el valor de un input type = "number" a un input type="text"?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

El problema es que cuando doy clic en las flechitas del input number no me pasa los valores al input text. Hasta ahora éste es el código que tengo.

```
<!-- código HGTML-->
<input type="hidden" name="Articulo" id="Articulo" value="<?php echo $row["idArticulo"]; ?> "/>

<input type="number" name="quanti"  id="quanti"  class="form-control" value="1"/>

<input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity<?php echo $row['idArticulo']; ?>"  class="form-control" value="1" />

<!-- código javascript-->
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var product_id = $('#Articulo').val(); //input tiene el idArticulo

            $("#quanti").keyup(function() {
                var recibir = $(this).val();

                //le envia el valor por teclado a quantity
                $("#quantity"+product_id).val(recibir);
                //¿y cómo capturo el valor por las flechitas del input number?
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: La función que buscas es `change()`

Comment: Sería:  $(document).change(function(){.......}); sería de esa manera? Disculpa, apenas estoy aprendiendo javascript

Comment: ¿Tienes  en el HTML un elemento que tenga el id: `"quantity"+product_id`? No lo veo en tu HTML, mientras que en jQuery intentas cambiar el valor de un elemento cuyo id sea esa combinación.

Comment: Gracias @Kevin usé el change y si funciona :)

Answer (score 2):

Lo siguiente agrega la fecha del campo "Fecha" al campo "Texto" al hacer cambios en el primero.

```js
var fecha= document.getElementById('fecha');
fecha.addEventListener('change', setText);

function setText() {
  var texto = document.getElementById('texto');
  texto.value = fecha.value;
}
```

```html
<div>Fecha: <input type="date" id="fecha"></div>
<div>Texto: <input type="text" id="texto"></div>
```

Básicamente consiste en registrar un evento al elemento "input" de la fecha de tipo "change".

Answer (score -2):

Como ya indicado @Kevin en comentarios, deberías usar `change` en lugar de `keyup`.

Veamos una prueba:

```js
        // $(document).ready(function() { obsoleto, usar function
           $(function() {
            var product_id = $('#Articulo').val(); //input tiene el idArticulo

            $("#quanti").change(function() {
                var recibir = $(this).val();

                //le envia el valor por teclado a quantity
                $("#quantity").val(recibir);
                //¿y cómo capturo el valor por las flechitas del input number?
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="Articulo" id="Articulo" value="1"/>

<input type="number" name="quanti"  id="quanti"  class="form-control" value="1"/>

<input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" class="form-control" value="1" />
```

**Nota:** Para tener el código al día, he usado `function` en lugar de `document.ready`, el cual es obsoleto desde jQuery 3 ([ver esta pregunta y sus respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/92628/29967))

Comment: Es correcto lo que respondes, pero el usuario quería cambiar el valor del `input` con id `quantity` por el de id `quanti` no solo al presionar un numero, sino que también al dar click en las flechas del elemento ubicadas a la derecha de este, por lo tanto la función es `change()`

Comment: De acuerdo @Kevin, pero esa intención me parece que fue indicada [en una edición posterior de la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/97153/revisions) mediante la modificación de parte esencial del código.

Comment: No discuto ese error pero, el problema planteado, cito textual de la pregunta `cuando doy clic en las flechitas del input number no me pasa los valores al input text` se refiere a lo comentado anteriormente y no fue editado, saludos

Comment: Buena observación @Kevin. Se me escapó ese detalle. Sugiero que aportes una respuesta con la solución. Saludos.