# ¿Cómo subo un input radio directamente a base de datos?

Tags: javascript, mysql

Tengo que hacer un cuestionario en el que cada estudiante elige una sola respuesta. Para ello lo estoy manejando con un **`<input type="radio>`**, lo que necesito es que después de que el estudiante elija la respuesta, se suba inmediatamente a la base de datos y ya no pueda seleccionar más.

Aquí el código de lo que tengo.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("input[id=Pedro]").click(function (){
                alert("Quien descubrió américa fue: Pedro Galibaldi");
            });

            $("input[id=Roberto]").click(function (){
                alert("Quien descubrió américa fue: Roberto Gomez");
            });

            $("input[id=Cristobal]").click(function (){
                alert("Quien descubrió américa fue: Cristobal Colon");
            });

            $("input[id=Isabel]").click(function (){
                alert("Quien descubrió américa fue: La reina isabel");
            });

            $("input[id=zidane]").click(function (){
                alert("Quien descubrió américa fue: zidane zidane");
            });
        });
</script>
```

Cada estudiante ingresa con su usuario y contraseña. Con ese usuario que lo identifica, él o ella, debe votar por el que desee e insertarse en la base de datos de la siguiente manera.

**Juan votó por "la reina isabel**
**Carlos votó por "Cristobal"**
**Luisa votó por "Roberto"**

Y así mismo quedar guardados en la base de datos.

Comment: Pero... ¿se trata de una sola pregunta o son varias? Si es una sola pregunta, la respuesta de @einer es válida, pero si es un formulario con varias preguntas de selección múltiple, es mejor desactivar el chekbox de cada pregunta una vez seleccionado y al final enviar el formulario completo... de ese modo evitas hacer llamadas constantes a la BD.

Comment: Es sólo una pregunta, es así tal cual como la mandé. Porque ya dependiendo de lo que respondan en esa pregunta se define para qué curso van... Pero si,  en resumidas palabras, es una sola pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Propongo esta solución más simple.

Al hacer click en una opción se desactivan las otras y se envía la información.

```js
$(function() {
  $(':radio').click(function() {
    $(':radio').prop("disabled", true);
    valor= $(this).val();
    /*Desde aquí invocas la función que agrega a la BD
      y le pasas el valor del radio seleccionado
      Ejemplo: agregarDatos(valor);*/
   // agregarDatos(valor);
      console.log("Aquí envías a la BD: "+valor);

  });

  function agregarDatos(valor){
    // console.log("Aquí envías a la BD: "+valor);
    /*Desde esta función puedes implementar una llamada a Ajax
     *que enviará la información del radio seleccionado a la BD
    */ 

        /* La petición Ajax sería algo así */

  var request = $.ajax({
   url: "agregar.php", //Archivo de servidor que inserta en la BD
   method: "POST",
   data: {radio: valor},
   dataType: "json"
  });
  
  request.done(function( data ) {
    console.log("Se agregaron los datos: "+data);
  });
  
  request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
   alert( "Error petición Ajax: " + textStatus );
  });      


   }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Opción 1:<input type="radio" id="p1" name="n1" value="Opción 1"><br /> Opción 2:<input type="radio" id="p2" name="n2" value="Opción 2"><br /> Opción 3:<input type="radio" id="p2" name="n3" value="Opción 3"><br />
```

Comment: Donde dice "Aquí envías a la base de BD:" ¿Sólo es poner el nombre de la tabla en la base de datos?

Comment: Es un mensaje de ejemplo para que veas que se recupera bien el valor del radio button seleccionado. Observa el código jQuery, donde dice:  `console.log("Aquí envías a la BD: "+$(this).val());`  tienes que hacer una llamada a la función que agrega la info a la base de datos, pasándole el valor `$(this).val()` que es el del rabio button seleccionado. Ejemplo, si tu función se llama agregarDatos, ahí harías una llamada como esta: `agregarDatos($(this).val());`  y en esta función tendrías el código que agrega a la BD. No sé si me explico.

Comment: Claro que si, el problema es que todavía no he hecho la inserción a la base de datos, entonces no sabría decirte.

Comment: Es que son dos preguntas en una. Para insertar en la BD tú tienes que enviar el valor del radio seleccionado al servidor mediante una petición Ajax y para ello tienes que implementar código escrito en lenguaje de servidor (PHP u otro). Es en ese código que se hace la inserción en la BD, no aquí. En Stackoverflow hay varias preguntas con buenas respuestas sobre cómo enviar datos al servidor mediante Ajax y jQuery.

Comment: ¿Y vos no me podrías colaborar con eso de la BD por Ajax y jQuery? por favor

Comment: @A.Cedano solo hay un detalle si se presiona la misma opción varias veces, se envía la misma respuesta varias veces `Aquí envías a la BD: Opción 2  
Aquí envías a la BD: Opción 2  
Aquí envías a la BD: Opción 2`

Comment: ¿Entonces cómo hacer para que no se repitan los datos @CesarRomero ?

Comment: Ya lo vi @CesarRomero, tienes razón, lo he modificado.

Comment: @CarlosOrtiz  he editado el código con un ejemplo de petición Ajax. Como te decía, es objeto de otra pregunta, ya que la petición Ajax implica otro archivo php que gestiona la inserción a la BD. Recomiendo que leas sobre el tema y veas algunos ejemplos aquí mismo.

Comment: @A.Cedano Pero la respuesta que dejaste no la entiendo mucho, no sé dónde o cómo debo insertar los valores a la BD si no sé cuál opción van a escoger los estudiantes.

Comment: @A.Cedano la verdad es que no llevo mucho en el tema de la programación, por eso se me hace un poco difícil. :/

Comment: ¿Cómo que no @CarlosOrtiz? Cuando llames a la función de esta manera: `function agregarDatos(valor){...`  le estás pasando en la variable `valor` la opción que ha sido escogida. Y en la petición Ajax, le pasas dicha variable al servidor con esto: `data: {radio: valor}` luego (aquí puedes pasar más datos, como el id del estudiante, etc. Luego el archivo PHP recibe ese dato y hace la inserción en la base de datos. Dicho archivo PHP debe ser programado para que al ejecutar la inserción devuelva un mensaje de éxito, lo mismo que si falla... en base a eso manejarás la respuesta de la petición Ajax.

Comment: @A.Cedano  ¿`valor` es la variable donde almaceno el insert?

Comment: No @CarlosOrtiz, `valor` es la variable que almacena la opción escogida por el estudiante, fíjate en el código jQuery: `valor= $(this).val();` El insert como te decía, se hace en el archivo PHP que llamas con Ajax, en el ejemplo ese archivo sería `agregar.php`. Dicho archivo tiene que conectarse a la BD y enviar el `INSERT INTO tabla (columna) VALUES (valor);` Para que entiendas mejor, puedes buscar en Google: _Cómo insertar datos en la base de datos mediante Ajax y jQuery_

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65198/discussion-between-carlos-ortiz-and-a-cedano).

Comment: @A.Cedano La verdad yo sé cómo insertar datos en la base de datos, el problema es que es algo fijo, pero como esto es lo que eligen los usuarios (estudiantes) entonces no sé cómo hacer el insert. O bueno, a decir verdad el values. No sé qué iría ahí.

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza el metodo `submit()` para enviar la informacion del formulario al servidor cauando se haga clic al radio:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("input[id=Pedro]").click(function (){
                alert("Quien descubrió américa fue: Pedro Galibaldi");
                $("idFormulario").submit();
            });

            $("input[id=Roberto]").click(function (){
                alert("Quien descubrió américa fue: Roberto Gomez");
                $("idFormulario").submit();
            });

            $("input[id=Cristobal]").click(function (){
                alert("Quien descubrió américa fue: Cristobal Colon");
                $("idFormulario").submit();
            });

            $("input[id=Isabel]").click(function (){
                alert("Quien descubrió américa fue: La reina isabel");
                $("idFormulario").submit();
            });

            $("input[id=zidane]").click(function (){
                alert("Quien descubrió américa fue: zidane zidane");
                $("idFormulario").submit();
            });
        });
```

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){` es deprecated desde jQuery 3. Considera responder con código actualizado para evitar la propagación de código obsoleto. Ver: [jQuery 3 declaró document.ready obsoleto ¿hay cambios también para window.load?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/92628/29967)

Comment: Todo dependeria de la version que el OP utilize no? Si no utiliza la v3, entiendo que seria innecesario especificarle ese dato.

Comment: ¿Osea que quedará funcionando así? `$(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});`

Comment: No, porque `function` funciona con casi todas las versiones de jQuery y es la forma recomendada, mientras que si usas `document.ready` cuando el OP tenga que pasar indefectiblemente a jQuery 4 ese código ya no funcionará, pues será sacado del core. Y si pasa ahora a jQuery 3 tendrá un warning de código obsoleto.

Comment: @Einer una pregunta, ¿Ese `$("idFormulario")` se declara ahí local o debo ponerlo en otro lado?

Comment: @CarlosOrtiz Actualmente estas enviando la informacion en la base de datos? Solo te falta que al dar clic se efectue el envio?

Comment: Me faltaba eso que enviaste y que quede almacenado en la base de datos, :D porque tengo a "1) Pedro Galibaldi, 2) Roberto Gomez, 3) Cristobal Colon 4) La reina Isabel, 5) zidane zidane"... Entonces necesito que si alguien vota por pedro, se suba a la base de datos **un voto para pedro emitido por (el estudiante)**

Comment: ¿Modifico la pregunta entonces o con eso entiendes?

Comment: Toda migración de versión en cualquier lenguaje, libreria, framework, etc suele tener una planificación, por mas mínima que fuese, donde se revisa cualquier incompatibilidad, por lo que que ambas son validas. A menos que el usuario indique la necesidad para una versión especifica.

Comment: Mi pregunté fue. Ya estas guardando en base de datos? Porque si todavía no lo haces de nada vale mi respuesta

Comment: @Einer Ya modifiqué la pregunta, la verdad pensé que iba a ser más sencillo hacer la base de datos.