# Devolver datos de un servidor php mediante AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Saludos, estoy haciendo una prueba sencilla, se trata de enviar un dato mediante AJAX a PHP para que me devuelva un datos, pero no se porque no me devuelve ningún dato. EL codigo JavaScript es el siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#login").submit(function(){

            var data_form=$(this).serialize();

            $.getJSON("login2.php", data_form, procesar_datos);

            return false;

        });

});

function procesar_datos(devueltos){

            $("#contenidos_externos").html("<p>" + devueltos.edad + "</p>");

}
```

Y el script PHP el siguiente

```
$user = $_GET['usuario'];

$el_array = new stdClass();

if ($user=="Name") {

    $el_array->Nombre = "Name";
    $el_array->Apellido = "Gómez";
    $el_array->Edad = "18";
    $json = json_encode($el_array);
    echo $json;


}
```

Comment: Te devuelbe algun error?

Comment: No estás mandando ninguna variable GET a través de la cadena de url, prueba `'login2.php?usuario=Name'`

Comment: El código PHP que tienes es muy precario. Por ejemplo, ¿qué ocurre si `$user` no es igual a `Name` o si `$_GET['usuario'];` está vacío? Lo mismo pasa en el jQuery, puede haber un error y esa posibilidad debe ser considerada y controlada en el código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probaste agregando el header json en el php?
ese es todo el codigo Php que usas? te falta esto

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Answer (score 4):

Vamos a escribir el código jQuery según se indica en la [documentación](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/), manejando las respuestas mediante `done` y `fail`.

Usaremos también código actualizado. Por ejemplo, `document.ready` es obsoleto desde jQuery 3 ([ver esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/92628/29967))

En cuanto al PHP, tenemos que darle todas las posibilidades. ¿Qué tal si ocurre un error? El PHP debe enviar en cualquier caso un json válido, el cual debe ser evaluado en la respuesta.

No se puede dar por supuesto que el código funcionará siempre como lo esperamos, puede haber datos erróneos y eso debe ser controlado **siempre**. Tu código no establece ningún control al respecto.

Veamos:

#### jQuery

```
    $(function() {
        var data_form={usuario:"Name"}; //usé una variable data_form temporal
        //$(this).serialize();

        var peticion = $.getJSON( "login2.php", data_form, function(data) 
        {
            console.log( "Petición enviada" );
        })

        .done(function(data) 
        {
            console.log( data);

            // Creamos una variable y evaluamos data
            var txtHTML;

            if (!data.Error)
            {

                txtHTML=data.Edad ;

            }else{

                txtHTML=data.Error ;

            }
            //Presentamos la variable según lo ocurrido
            $("#contenidos_externos").html("<p>" + txtHTML + "</p>");

        })

        .fail(function() 
        {
            console.log( "error en la petición ajax" );
        })     

    });
```

---

#### PHP

El PHP evalúa:

1. Si hay en realidad una variable `usuario` en GET
2. Si `$user = Name`

Ocurra lo que ocurra, crea un json con información sobre lo sucedido del lado del servidor. Luego, en la parte `done` de Ajax leerás el json para determinar lo que hay en él, por ejemplo, si hay error, imprimir el mensaje de error, y si no hay error, imprimir los datos de la persona.

```
<?php


    $user = $_GET['usuario'];

    // Hay que evaluar todas las posibilidades ...
    // No podemos suponer que todo funciona como debería funcionar
    if(!empty($user)) 
    {
        $el_array = new stdClass();

        if ($user=="Name") 
        {
            $el_array->Nombre = "Name";
            $el_array->Apellido = "Gómez";
            $el_array->Edad = "18";

        }else{

            $el_array->Error = "No existe la persona $user";
        }

    }else{

        $el_array->Error = "El dato Name no existe en la petición";

    }

    $json = json_encode($el_array);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo $json;

?>
```

---

#### HTML

```
<div id="contenidos_externos"></div>
```

---

#### Prueba

Me arroja esto en la consola:

```
[Log] Petición enviada (test.php, line 17)
[Log] {Nombre: "Name", Apellido: "Gómez", Edad: "18"} (test.php, line 22)
```

Y aparece la edad en la página.

Prueba también con datos erróneos y verás que el código funcionará siempre.

Espero te sirva.