# regresar mensaje de php a HTML

Tags: php

hola a todos estoy creando un sitio de contacto, tengo mi archivo personal.php (formulario) y GuardarPersonal.PHP (INSER de los datos)

en mi GuardarPersonal.PHP tengo esto

```html
$sql = "SELECT Numero_Empleado FROM personal WHERE '$_Numero'";
 $result = $conn->query($sql);
 $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
 if ($count == 1) {
 echo "<br />". "El Usuario ya a sido Registrado." . "<br />";
 echo "<a href='Location: ../tables.php'>Por favor verificar la informacion</a>";
```

quiero regresar el mensaje de "El usuario ya esta dado de alta" a mi archivo personal.php

Comment: Tienes que usar Ajax para eso, de ese modo comunicas datos entre ambos archivos de forma transparente.

Comment: tienes algún ejemplo

Comment: Aquí hay varios ejemplos. Si escribes `Ajax` en el buscador encontrarás varios ejemplos bien explicados de como funciona. Ahora mismo no tengo ninguno a mano.

Comment: Quizá [este sea uno de los ejemplos más sencillos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/103252/29967), que ayudaría a comprender cómo funciona Ajax. Lo importante es que en el servidor tú puedes ejecutar lo que sea y devolverlo de nuevo al cliente para presentarlo en pantalla o hacer otras operaciones.

Comment: ya lo tengo solucionado gracias