# Despues de ejecutar desde el boton guardar , se salta una alerta de exito y muestra la de error

Tags: php, ajax, try, cacht

Estoy guardando unos registros con Ajax, en un servidor de pruebas después de hacer clic en "guardar", debería mostrar un sweet alert señalando que se guardo con éxito,  en lugar de eso muestra el sweet alert de error.  Cabe mencionar que en el equipo de desarrollo funciona sin ningún problema.

a continuación solo pondré el código del Ajax donde se lleva a cabo el evento de guardado.

```js
                e.preventDefault();
                if(formAviso_Privacidad) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "post",
                        url: "guardarAvisoP.php",
                        async: true,
                        data: {
                            "Id": Id,
                            "Id_Grupo": Id_Grupo,
                            "FechaR":fechaR,
                            "MantenerR": mantenerR ,
                            "RegistroF": registroF,
                            "VinculacionE": vinculacionE,
                            "DivulgacionA": divulgacionA,
                            "Id_Usuario": id_Usuario   
                        },
                        success: function(msg){
                            //alert(msg);
                            
                        swal.fire({
                            icon: 'success',
                            title:'Registro Guardado con Exito',
                            html: 'Haga clic en ACEPTAR para cerrar',
                            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                            confirmButtonText: 'ACEPTAR'
                        }).then(function() {
                          
                          $Id_Alumno = document.getElementById('Id_Alumno').value;
                          window.location.replace("/proyecto/aviso_privacidad.php?id_alumno="+$Id_Alumno);
                          });
                        console.log("Alert Callback");
                        },
                        error: function(){
                        swal.fire("Error!..No se pudo llevar a cabo el registro", "Haga Clic para Cerrar", "error");
                        console.log("Alert Callback");
                            
                        }
                    });
                }
```

En el equipo donde se desarrolla realiza todo sin problema, haces clic en guardar, despliega la sweet alert de que se guardo exitosamente, le das clic en el botón ok de este sweet alert, se cierra, y se redirecciona a la pagina indicada. si guarda los registros.

En el servidor de pruebas, envía la sweet alert de error, la cierras, redirecciona a la pagina indicada, al revisar la BD si están los registros guardados.

Estuve leyendo algunas paginas y foros, mencionan algo del try catch se podría utilizar esto
para que despliegue la sweet alert correcta ?.

En la conexion PDO que utilizo tengo estas lineas:

```html
public function insertar($consulta, $error=NULL)
    {
        if( !empty($consulta) )
        {
            self::conectar();
            try
            {
                $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($consulta);
                $stmt->execute();

                $stmt->closeCursor();
                $this->pdo = NULL;

                return;
            }
            catch(Exception $e)
            {die($error);}

        }
        else
        {return 0;}
    }`
```

¿ Como puedo utilizar esto del try catch  en Ajax ?

Comment: Pero si en un entorno funciona y en otro no, el problema podría ser del código en el servidor, no en Ajax. Convendría ver qué dice el mensaje de error cuando falla. Por ejemplo, modifica así tu parte de error: **`error: function (jqxhr, exception) {`** y pon dentro algo como `alert(jqxhr.responseText)`

Comment: A. Cedano se supone que la exception te estaría dando cierta información cuando no se puede procesar un insert, delete o update ,  aquí el detalle es que si lleva a cabo la inserción de los datos,  lo que hace de manera errónea es enviar la ventana de sweet alert indicando que no se pudo registrar el dato.   Por eso quería ver si puedo validar el success y el error con try catch pero no le entiendo muy bien a lo que leí.

Comment: Voy a probar con lo que dices,  error: function (jqxhr, exception) { alert(jqxhr.responseText)  } haber que me muestra comento mas delante.  Gracias

Comment: Nooop, estás confundido en ese punto. La parte `error`  de tu petición Ajax es para manejar errores propios de la petición, tales como errores 500 que ocurrieron en el servidor, o un error 404 de página no encontrada, etc. Otra cosa son los errores en la lógica del programa en el servidor. Ese tipo de errores entrarán en la parte del `success`, porque realmente no hubo ningún problema en la petición, la  misma se hizo con éxito, sólo que no se insertaron datos o lo que sea. Debes manejar eso desde el `success`, y desde el servidor, puedes responder con un código para saber qué pasó.

Comment: A. Cedano agrege las lineas de error que me señalaste pero se las puse tanto al success como al error,  bueno en la consola me postea este mensaje: "XHR POST http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/proyecto/guardarAvisoP.php    [HTTP/1 500 Internal Server Error 126ms   que técnicamente me esta indicando que no encuentra el archivo para procesar los datos,  Pero si procesa e inserta los datos en la BD

Comment: A.Cedano  ya encontré la fuente del error.  Ya se corrigió,  ahora a realizar las pruebas necesarias para posteriormente subir a producción este modulo.  Te agradezco el tiempo que te tomas en compartir tus conocimientos.  Dios te Bendiga.  Saludos

Comment: Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto. Para que no te encuentres perdido en Ajax es importante tener presente, que el código entrará en la parte de `error` solamente cuando haya ocurrido errores de cliente o de servidor, son los errores con código del 400 al 599 ([ver aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)). Si ninguno de esos errores ocurren, entrará en el `success`, retornando por lo general un código `200` u otro. Si hubo un error en la lógica de tu programa, Ajax no puede saber eso, de modo que los errores de lógica se manejan en el `success`, verificando la respuesta.

Comment: [Mira aquí un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/103252/29967). Aunque en ese código, en vez de `success` y `error` se usa `done` y `fail`, más recomendable, porque `success` / `error` quedaron obsoletos desde jQuery 3. En ese código, dentro de `done` se manejan errores de lógica. En la implementación PHP simplemente se puso a la respuesta una clave `Error` cuando `$user` estuviera vacío. Para Ajax, pase lo que pase esa petición es exitosa, porque no ocurrió ningún error de red o de servidor. En tu caso, estaba entrando en `error` porque estaba ocurriendo un error `500`.

Comment: No te lleves tampoco de que *los datos se insertaban en la base de datos*. Eso puede ocurrir perfectamente, pero si posterior a la inserción algo pasa, como que te olvidaste cerrar la línea siguiente a la inserción con `;` o lo que sea, la inserción ocurrirá de hecho, pero Ajax recibirá un error `500` debido a ese `;` que se encontró después en el código y tu petición entrará en el bloque de `error`. Por eso siempre hay que depurar el código, no dar por supuesto nada. El hecho de que los datos se inserten no debe hacer pensar que por eso todo está bien del lado del servidor.

Comment: A. Cedano gracias por tus aportaciones,  lo reviso en cuanto tenga oportunidad.  Todo este show se derivo de una consulta a nivel de base de datos, que se supone valida que la insercion o el update se haga,  resulta que esa linea que llama a esa consulta no hace nada, y provocaba un error, lo detecte en la etapa de desarrollo pero como no me afectaba para nada,  lo deje pasar...  Ya que estaba en el servidor de pruebas , pues si me ocasiono que el error detectado, dispara la ventana de error.

Comment: Ya que disparaba la ventana de error,  obviamente omitia todas las instrucciones que segian al sucess lo que me ocasionaba mas detalles a revisar, bueno se logro detectar que ocasionaba "la falla" se eliminaron esas lineas y todo funciono de manera adecuada segun lo que se pretendia desde un principio.  Agradezco que seas tan efusivo en tus aportaciones, se aprende mucho , he dado seguimiento a muchas participaciones tuyas y siempre suman.  Gracias.