# ocultar y mostrar boton si el type="file" esta vacio o no

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

Buenos días, estoy intentando mostrar y ocultar el botón delete si el file esta vacío o no y no sé muy bien como hacerlo, creo que es cun un display show y hide, pero no estoy seguro

HTML

```
<div style="margin-left: 225px; margin-top: -65px;" id="carta_nominador_div">
    <label for="carta_nominador" style="color: #fff; background: #000; width: 142px; height: 52px;  border-radius: 100px;cursor: pointer;">
        <span class="iborrainputfile" style="margin-left: 27px;">ATTACH FILE</span>
    </label>
    <span id="fichero_seleccionado" style="font-size: 14px; margin-left: 160px; margin-top: -33px; position: absolute;"></span>
    <input type="file" name="carta_nominador" id="carta_nominador" class="validaCarta inputfile inputfile-1">

    </div>

    <script>
        $("#carta_nominador").change(function(){
            var fichero_seleccionado = $(this).val();
            var nombre_fichero_seleccionado = fichero_seleccionado.replace(/.*[\/\\]/, ''); //Eliminamos el path hasta el fichero seleccionado

            $("#fichero_seleccionado").text(nombre_fichero_seleccionado);
        });
    </script>

    <div class="boton" style="width:110px; margin: -45px 0 5px 600px;"><a href="#" id="delCarta" style="position: absolute; color: #fff;text-decoration: none;text-transform: uppercase;margin-top: 15px;margin-left: -25px;">Delete</a></div>
```

JQUERY

```
$('#delCarta').click(
        function(){
            clearFileInputField('carta_nominador_div');
            clearNameFile('fichero_seleccionado');
            $("#carta_nominador").change(function(){
                var fichero_seleccionado = $(this).val();
                var nombre_fichero_seleccionado = fichero_seleccionado.replace(/.*[\/\\]/, ''); //Eliminamos el path hasta el fichero seleccionado

                $("#fichero_seleccionado").text(nombre_fichero_seleccionado);
                            });
                        }
                    );
                });
                function clearNameFile(tagId) {
                    //document.getElementById(tagId).textContent = "";
                    $("#"+tagId).text("");
                }
                function clearFileInputField(tagId) {
                    document.getElementById(tagId).innerHTML = 
                                    document.getElementById(tagId).innerHTML;
                }
```

Cómo podría hacer que esté oculto el botón DELETE y cuando se seleccione un archivo se muestre el botón?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Podrías empezar con el botón oculto (añadiéndole una clase `invisible` que tenga `display:none`)

```
<a href="#" id="delCarta" class="invisible" style="position: absolute; color: #fff;text-decoration: none;text-transform: uppercase;margin-top: 15px;margin-left: -25px;">Delete</a>
```

y en el evento `change` de `#carta_nominador` verificar si el contenido es no vacío para quitar o añadir la clase `invisible`

```
   $("#carta_nominador").change(function(){
        var fichero_seleccionado = $(this).val();
        var nombre_fichero_seleccionado = fichero_seleccionado.replace(/.*[\/\\]/, ''); 

        if(nombre_fichero_seleccionado==='') {
           $('#delCarta').addClass('invisible');
        } else {
           $('#delCarta').removeClass('invisible'); 
        }

        $("#fichero_seleccionado").text(nombre_fichero_seleccionado);
    });
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya me funcionó

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear una variable booleana, que controlará la visibilidad del botón. De entrada esta variable será `true`, para iniciar el botón desactivado. Y cambiará en el `on.change` del botón que selecciona los archivos.

Dicha variable será `false` únicamente cuando haya un archivo seleccionado y cambiará entonces el estado del botón `Delete`.

**Notas:**

- Las buenas prácticas recomiendan encerrar todo lo relativo al DOM dentro de `function`... hay que tener en cuenta que `document.ready`  es obsoleto desde jQuery 3.
- El uso de `prop` es recomendado, con respecto al uso de `attr`.
- Viendo que en tu HTML aplicas estilos directamente, comentarte que no es una buena práctica colocar estilos directamente en los elementos HTML, se recomienda dar a esos elementos nombres de clases y aplicar los estilos vía CSS. De ese modo, los elementos son más independientes y si quieres cambiar el estilo sólo tienes que modificar el CSS sin tener que buscar todos los elementos HTML para actualizarlos.

```js
/*Se recomienda encerrar todo el código del DOM en function*/
$(function() {
  var bolDisabled = true;
  $('#btnDelete').prop('disabled', bolDisabled);

  $('#carta_nominador').on("change", function() {
    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    if (!inputVal == '') {
      var bolDisabled = false;
    }
    $('#btnDelete').prop('disabled', bolDisabled);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="fichero_seleccionado" style="font-size: 14px; margin-left: 160px; margin-top: -33px; position: absolute;"></span>
<input type="file" name="carta_nominador" id="carta_nominador" class="validaCarta inputfile inputfile-1">
<hr />
<button id="btnDelete">Delete</button>
```

---

**P.D.**: Sobre lo comentado más arriba sobre `document.ready` puedes ver la siguiente pregunta:

- [jQuery 3 declaró document.ready obsoleto ¿hay cambios también para window.load?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/92628/29967)

Pero es muy importante no confundir `document.ready` con `window.load`. Son dos cosas muy diferentes. Si hay dudas sobre las diferencias entre ambas, puedes consultar la respuesta a esta pregunta:

- [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre window.onload y $(document).ready()?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/51946/29967)