# Marcar opciones de select al traer los datos

Tags: javascript, php, html, postgresql

estoy haciendo un CRUD el cual tiene interesados y cursos. Quiero que al editar los interesados me traiga los cursos en los que esta interesados. Estos cursos se muestra con un select multiple pero no se como hacer para marcarlos como selected.

La consulta a la DB es a traves de php, y toda la funcionalidad la estoy haciendo con JS.

Hice lo siguiente pero no funciona

```
this.editar = (id) => {
    var form = new FormData();
    form.append("id", id);
    fetch("../controllers/editar.php", {
        method: "POST",
        body: form,
    })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            document.getElementById("id_interesado").value = data.id_interesado;
            document.getElementById("nombre").value = data.nombre;
            document.getElementById("apellido").value = data.apellido;
            document.getElementById("telefono").value = data.telefono;
            document.getElementById("email").value = data.email;
            document.getElementById("direccion").value = data.direccion;
            document.getElementById("numero").value = data.numero;
            document.getElementById("localidad").value = data.localidad;
            document.getElementById("dni").value = data.dni;
            var form_cursos = new FormData();
            form_cursos.append("id_interesado", data.id_interesado);
            fetch("../controllers/editar_cursos_interes.php", {
                method: "POST",
                body: form_cursos,
            })
                .then((res) => res.json())
                .then((data) => {
                    var ids_cursos = Array();
                    data.forEach((item) => {
                        ids_cursos.push(item.id_curso);
                    })
                    ids_cursos.forEach((item) => {
                        if (document.getElementById("curso_interes").value in ids_cursos) {
                            document.getElementById("curso_interes").setAttribute("selected", true);
                        }
                    })
                })
                .catch((error) => console.log(error));
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que entiendo lo que quieres es marcar como seleccionado un item de un select, siendo así puedes hacer algo simple como esto:

```
let element = document.getElementById("select");
element.value = value; // Value puede ser el ID o el valor del select
```

Por ejemplo:

```js
let element = document.getElementById("family");
element.value = 4;


let element2 = document.getElementById("familys");
element2.querySelector("option[value=\"1\"]").selected = true;
element2.querySelector("option[value=\"3\"]").selected = true;
```

```html
<select id="family" name="family">
      <option value="1">Yo</option>
      <option value="2">Hermano</option>
      <option value="3">Papa</option>
      <option value="4">Mama</option>
</select>


<select id="familys" name="family" multiple>
      <option value="1">Yo</option>
      <option value="2">Hermano</option>
      <option value="3">Papa</option>
      <option value="4">Mama</option>
</select>
```

Se marcará mama, solo tienes que tener en el select la información y decirle el **value** que corresponda.

Comment: Hasta ahi perfecto, y cuando son varias opciones, como se hace?

Comment: @LucasLeone te puede servir ésta respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/323890/155688

Comment: @LucasLeone Te puse un ejemplo muy sencillo de como sería en uno múltiple, saludos.

Comment: `DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Element': 'option[value=1]' is not a valid selector.
    at http://localhost/beca/app/assets/code.js:130:37
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost/beca/app/assets/code.js:129:30`

Comment: ese error me sale

Comment: @LucasLeone Donde dice value=1 tiene que ser el ID si usas ID o el que corresponda procura también que quede algo así: `element2.querySelector("option[value="+VARIABLE+"]").selected = true;
` donde variable es el ID o el value que corresponda, yo he puesto 1 porque en el ejemplo hay uno que tiene 1 en el value. Saludos