# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que me sume puntos en un test con jquery?

Tags: jquery

Quiero hacer un ejercicio de practicar como ir incrementando una variable resultado, según las respuestas que vaya eligiendo

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#comprobar").click(function(){

    var nota_examen = 0;

    if($(this).is(".correcto")) {

        nota_examen++;
        alert(nota_examen);
    };
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<p>En una página  HTML solo puede aparecer una id única vez </p>
<input type="radio" class="correcto" value="a" name="pregunta2">Cierto<br/>
<input type="radio" class="opciones" value="b" name="pregunta2">Falso<br/></div>


<input type="button" value="Enviar" id="comprobar">
```

Comment: Quieres que sume al presionar el radio button o solo en el botón enviar?

Comment: Quiero que la variable nota_examen se vaya incrementando si la respuesta es correcta

Comment: La variable **nota_examen** debe ser global y no dentro de la función.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que entiendo quieres ir aumentando una variable según cada respuesta correcta, si es asi el codigo del javascript deberia ser asi:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#comprobar").click(function(){

    var nota_examen = 0;

    radio= $(".correcto");
    radio.each(function(){
        if($(this).prop("checked")){
            nota_examen++;
        }        
    });
    alert(nota_examen);
});
```

***Explicación***

La variable radio guarda una colección de elementos con la clase "correcto"

Luego se recorre la colección preguntando si se encuentra con estado "check", si el mismo se encuentra en dicho estado la variable nota_examen se incrementara

Answer (score 4):

El contexto completo siempre es importante.

En este caso veamos un contexto con varias preguntas de selección múltiple.

Al `div` que contiene las preguntas vamos a otorgar una clase `questions`. Luego podremos alcanzar únicamente los checkbox seleccionados mediante este selector: `'.questions input:checked'` y dentro de un `each` vamos a verificar si el elemento tiene la clase `correcto` con  [`hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) para aumentar en uno el acumulador en ese caso.

También he usado `function` en vez de `document.ready`, el cual está obsoleto<sup>1</sup> desde jQuery 3.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#comprobar").click(function() {
    var nota_examen = 0;
    $('.questions input:checked').each(function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass('correcto')) {
        nota_examen++;
      }
    });
    alert(nota_examen);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="questions">
  <p>1. ¿De qué color es el caballo blanco de Napoleón? </p>
  <input type="radio" class="correcto" value="a" name="q1">Blanco<br/>
  <input type="radio" class="incorrecto" value="b" name="q1">Negro<br/>
  <p>2. ¿En qué año murió CarloMagno? </p>
  <input type="radio" class="incorrecto" value="a" name="q2">En el último<br/>
  <input type="radio" class="correcto" value="b" name="q2">En el 814 dC<br/>
</div>

<hr />
<input type="button" value="Enviar" id="comprobar">
```

---

## Notas

1. El problema ha sido abordado en esta pregunta: *[jQuery 3 declaró document.ready obsoleto ¿hay cambios también para window.load?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/92628/29967)*

Answer (score 0):

Espero entender correctamente la pregunta, creo que lo podrías hacer con el método "**change**" de JQuery, este está ejecutándose cada vez que se realice un cambio en el *input*.

Cuando su input seleccionado posee la clase "*correcto*", su `nota_examen` se incrementará y si no está seleccionado, volverá a 0;

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var nota_examen = 0;

$("#comprobar").click(function() {
  
   if(nota_examen == 0) {
    alert('Respuesta incorrecta');
   } else {
    alert('Correcto!');
   }
  
});

$("body input[name='pregunta2']").each(function() {
  $(this).change(function() {
      if($(this).hasClass("correcto")) {

        nota_examen++;
        
      } else {

        nota_examen = 0;

      }
      
      console.log(nota_examen);
    });
});


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<p>En una página  HTML solo puede aparecer una id única vez </p>
<input type="radio" class="correcto" value="a" name="pregunta2">Cierto<br/>
<input type="radio" class="opciones" value="b" name="pregunta2">Falso<br/></div>


<input type="button" value="Enviar" id="comprobar">
```

```html
div>
<p>En una página  HTML solo puede aparecer una id única vez </p>
<input type="radio" class="correcto" value="a" name="pregunta2">Cierto<br/>
<input type="radio" class="opciones" value="b" name="pregunta2">Falso<br/></div>


<input type="button" value="Enviar" id="comprobar">
```