# $(document).on('click', function (e) obsoleto

Tags: jquery

En las nuevas versiones de `jQuery` se emplea la ejecución del código así: `$(function () {});` pero ahora he visto mencionar que la siguiente forma: `$(document).on('click', function (e)` es obsoleto, pero nadie menciona por comentarios como se debe emplear ahora en la actualidad.

¿Cómo debe quedar ahora en la actualidad el ejemplo propuesto en mi pregunta?

La versión que estoy utilizando es v3.4.1

El ejemplo propuesto, lo que me permite es hacer un evento en el que si el usuario da click fuera de un contenedor, este se cierra, para ser más especifico un menú, pero si estoy en el contenedor del menú, navegando o dando click en ello, se mantiene visible, activo.

Pero si intento usar funciones no obsoletas, intentando lo siguiente:

```
$( "html" ).click(function()
```

O

```
$( "body" ).click(function()
```

Esto no funciona.

Comment: Que versión de jquery?

Comment: @BetaM La versión que estoy utilizando es v3.4.1

Comment: Aquí hay dos preguntas una es sobre el código obsoleto y otra sobre el problema del *click*, te sugiero que te centres en una o separes las preguntas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TLDR;

jQuery implementó históricamente varias formas de escuchar que ciertos elementos del DOM estuviesen listos (ready).

Son los siguientes:

- `$( handler )`
- `$( document ).ready( handler )`
- `$( "document" ).ready( handler )`
- `$( "img" ).ready( handler )`
- `$().ready( handler )`

A partir de la versión 3, jQuery quiso poner un poco de orden en medio de ese lío y decidió **que la forma recomendada es la primera**, declarando todas las demás obsoletas.

Realmente, lo que tú preguntas no tiene **nada que ver con esto**. En jQuery la escucha de elemntos por tipo (`body`, `html`), se hace exactamente como la tienes. O sea, que esto es correcto y no obsoleto:

```
  $("html").click(function() {
    //Aquí bloque de código
  });
```

Y esto también:

```
  $("body").click(function() {
    //Aquí bloque de código
  });
```

Ahora bien, en Javascript se recomienda siempre someter el bloque de código a una escucha de que el DOM haya sido cargado. Y ahí si entra tu duda, porque como complemento a tu código conviene poner un bloque que escuche el document.ready y para ello hay que usar la sintaxis que recomienda jQuery a partir de la versión 3:

```js
$(function() {

  $("html").click(function() {
    console.log('Listener de html: ¡Funciona!');
  });

  $("body").click(function() {
    console.log('Listener de body: ¡También funciona!');
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <button>Click aquí</button>
</body>
```

---

Como aporte, te dejo aquí traducción de la [documentación de jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/ready/#ready-handler) sobre este caso de obsolescencia concreto:

> jQuery ofrece varias formas de adjuntar una función que se ejecutará
> cuando el DOM esté listo. Todas las siguientes sintaxis son
> equivalentes:
>
> - `$( handler )`
> - `$( document ).ready( handler )`
> - `$( "document" ).ready( handler )`
> - `$( "img" ).ready( handler )`
> - `$().ready( handler )`
>
> A partir de jQuery 3.0, solo se recomienda la primera sintaxis; las
> otras sintaxis siguen funcionando pero están en desuso. Esto se debe a
> que la selección no influye en el comportamiento del método
> `.ready()`, que es ineficaz y puede dar lugar a suposiciones
> incorrectas sobre el comportamiento del método. Por ejemplo, la
> tercera sintaxis funciona con "document" que no selecciona nada. La
> cuarta sintaxis espera a que el documento esté listo pero implica
> (incorrectamente) que espera a que las imágenes estén listas.
>
> También hay `$(document).on("ready", handler)`, obsoleto a partir de
> jQuery 1.8 y eliminado en jQuery 3.0. Tenga en cuenta que si el DOM
> está listo antes de que se adjunte este evento, el controlador no se
> ejecutará.
>
> El método `.ready()` se usa típicamente con una función anónima:
>
> ```
> $( document ).ready(function() {
>   // Handler for .ready() called.
> });
> ```
>
> Que es equivalente a la forma recomendada de llamada:
>
> ```
> $(function() {
>   // Handler for .ready() called.
> });
> ```

#### Rendimiento del evento

Cuando asignas eventos de escucha debes hilar fino, porque no es lo mismo asignar ciertos eventos de escucha globales (a todo el `body` por ejemplo) que asignarlo a elementos más específicos. Si abusas de esa práctica tu código podría verse gravemente ralentizado.

Esto viene claramente explicado en [la documentación de jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/on/) en el apartado **Event performance**:

> En la mayoría de los casos, un evento como un clic ocurre con poca
> frecuencia y el rendimiento no es una preocupación importante. Sin
> embargo, los eventos de alta frecuencia, como el movimiento del mouse
> o el desplazamiento, pueden dispararse docenas de veces por segundo, y
> en esos casos se vuelve más importante usar los eventos con prudencia.
> El rendimiento se puede aumentar reduciendo la cantidad de trabajo
> realizado en el propio controlador, almacenando en caché la
> información que necesita el controlador en lugar de volver a
> calcularla, o limitando la cantidad de actualizaciones de página
> reales mediante `setTimeout`.
>
> Adjuntar muchos controladores de eventos delegados cerca de la parte
> superior del árbol del documento puede degradar el rendimiento. Cada
> vez que ocurre el evento, jQuery debe comparar todos los selectores de
> todos los eventos adjuntos de ese tipo con cada elemento en la ruta
> desde el objetivo del evento hasta la parte superior del documento.
> Para obtener el mejor rendimiento, adjunte eventos delegados en una
> ubicación de documento lo más cerca posible de los elementos de
> destino. Evite el uso excesivo de `document` o `document.body` para
> eventos delegados en documentos grandes.
>
> jQuery puede procesar selectores simples de la etiqueta de formulario
> `#id.class` muy rápidamente cuando se utilizan para filtrar eventos
> delegados. Entonces, "`#myForm`", "`a.external`" y "`button`" son
> selectores rápidos. Los eventos delegados que utilizan selectores más
> complejos, en particular los jerárquicos, pueden ser varias veces más
> lentos, aunque siguen siendo lo suficientemente rápidos para la
> mayoría de las aplicaciones. Los selectores jerárquicos a menudo se
> pueden evitar simplemente adjuntando el controlador a un punto más
> apropiado del documento. Por ejemplo, en lugar de `$( "body" ).on( "click", "#commentForm .addNew", addComment )` utilice `$( "#commentForm" ).on( "click", ".addNew", addComment )`.

#### Preguntas relacionadas

- [jQuery 3 declaró document.ready obsoleto ¿hay cambios también para window.load?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/92628/29967)
- [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre window.onload y $(document).ready()?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/51946/29967)