# Mi peticion ajax no regresa datos

Tags: php, html, ajax, bootstrap, pdo

Estoy intentado hacer un select anidado con php, ajax y mysql en un disño MVC.

En el siguiente select muestro los datos (Nombre de cursos) que tengo en mi base de datos, estos se muestran sin problema.

```
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="curso">Nombre del curso</label>
                            <select id="curso" class="form-control" name="curso">
                                <option selected="selected">Selecionar curso</option>
                                <?php foreach ($data['asignar'] as $cur) {?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $cur["nombreDelCurso"]; ?>">
                                    <?php echo $cur['nombreDelCurso']; ?>
                                </option>
                                <?php }?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Y al seleccionar el nombre del curso me deberia mostrar el nombre del instructor en este campo.

```
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="instructor">Nombre del instructor</label>
                            <select id="instructor" class="form-control" name="instructor">
                                <option id="nombreInstructor"></option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Mi peticion AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#curso").change(function() {
    var id = $(this).find(":selected").val();
    var dataString = 'asistencia=' + id;
    console.log(dataString);
    $.ajax({
        url : '../../tec/Config/cursos.php',
        dataType: "json",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(employeeData) {
            console.log(employeeData);
            if (employeeData) {
                $("#heading").show();
                $("#no_records").hide();
                $("#nombreInstructor").text(employeeData.nombreDelInstructor);
                $("#records").show();
            } else {
                $("#heading").hide();
                $("#records").hide();
                $("#no_records").show();
            }
        }
    });
})
});
```

Mi nueva conexion

```
require 'Config.php';

if ($_REQUEST['asistencia']) {
    echo 'alert("no hay anad")';
    $data = new Conexion();
    $conexion = $data->conect();
    $strquery = "SELECT * FROM cursos WHERE nombreDelCurso='" . $_REQUEST['asistencia'] . "'";
    $result = $conexion->prepare($strquery);
    $result->execute();
    $data = $result->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo json_encode ($data);
} else {
   echo 0;
}
```

Como se muestra en la siguiente imagen en el campo instructor no muestra nada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Has verificado lo que te devuelve el `echo json_encode($data);`?  ¿Lo puedes agregar a la pregunta con el enlace [edit]?

Comment: empezaría probando a quitar el `echo 'alert("no hay anad")';`, que convierte la respuesta en un texto no válido como json

Comment: Eso no me muestra nada y ya lo quite

Answer (score 1):

Veo varios problemas en tu código, y los voy a enumerar:

- Usas [funciones de jQuery obsoletas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/92628/29967)
- Usas código vulnerable (inyección SQL)
- Convendría que uses un método más específico, con `GET` bastaría para este caso
- Tu estilo de responder en el servidor **no es coherente** con lo que el cliente espera. Indicas un `dataType: 'json'` en el cliente y en el servidor respondes no importa qué. Debes controlar el flujo del código en el servidor para responder **siempre** un json, pase lo que pase, controlando además TODOS los posibles errores. No deberías nunca programar de una forma ingenua, como de hecho haces.

Aplicaremos ahora todo lo dicho en tu código:

### En el cliente

```
/*
   $(document).ready(function() {
   en OBSOLETO desde jQuery 3
*/

$(function() {
    $("#curso").change(function() {
        var id = $(this).find(":selected").val();
        var mData = {asistencia: id};

        $.ajax({
            url : '../../tec/Config/cursos.php',
            dataType: "json",
            data: mData,
            method: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            success: function(employeeData) {
                console.log(employeeData);
                if (employeeData.status) {
                    /*
                       Puede que la forma de lectura
                       deba variar, según la estructura
                       de la respuesta
                     */
                    console.log(employeeData.data);
                    $("#heading").show();
                    $("#no_records").hide();
                    $("#nombreInstructor").text(employeeData.nombreDelInstructor);
                    $("#records").show();
                } else {
                    $("#heading").hide();
                    $("#records").hide();
                    $("#no_records").show();
                }
            }
        });
    })
});
```

---

### En el Servidor

```
/*
   Si tu versión de PHP es anterior a la v. 7
   cambia la siguiente línea por esto:
   $curso=!empty($_GET['asistencia']) ? $_GET['asistencia'] : null;
*/
$curso=$_GET['asistencia'] ?? null;
/*
   Variable para seguir el flujo del programa
*/
$mData=array();

if ($curso) {
    require 'Config.php';
    $data = new Conexion();
    $conexion = $data->conect();
    if ($conexion) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM cursos WHERE nombreDelCurso=:curso";
        $result = $conexion->prepare($sql);
        $result->bindParam(':curso', $curso, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->execute();
        $data = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if ($data) {
            $mData['status']=true;
            $mData['data']=$data;
        } else {
            $mData['status']=false;
            $mData['msg']='No se encontraron datos';
        }
    } else {
        $mData['status']=false;
        $mData['msg']='No hay conexión';
    }
} else {
    $mData['status']=false;
    $mData['msg']='No se enviaron datos desde el cliente';
}
echo json_encode ($mData);
```

Si observas, en el servidor he diseñado una estrategia que consiste en lo siguiente:

- Si algún error ocurre, pondré en `$mData` una clave `status` con valor `false` y pondré también una clave `msg` con un mensaje descriptivo del error.
- Si ningún error ocurre, pondré en `$mData`una clave `status` con valor `true` y pondré también una clave `data` con los datos.

Si observas, el código del cliente también es conforme con este *estilo*. Basta con esto: `if (employeeData.status) {` para saber que hay datos, y luego usarás `employeeData.data` para obtener los datos.

OJO: puede que `fetchAll` te devuelva **varias filas** o una sola fila, metida en un índice `0` de un array. Sea como sea, tu lectura en el cliente debe ser conforme a la estructura de la respuesta. Dado que esto es algo contextual, no he modificado nada en el cliente al respecto, simplemente te puse allí un  `console.log` con la forma correcta de depurar. Adapta la lectura según la realidad de tus datos.

Comment: , Es la primera vez que json y ajax motivo por el cual desconozco mucho sobre estos temas, y gracias por responder a mi pregunta. estare revisando mis peticiones ajax

Comment: No me regresa datos, no se que estara mal

Comment: @AltC ¿cuál de los mensajes muestra?

Comment: no me regresa ningun mensaje

Comment: @AltC ¿has revisado la consola? Yo puse esto: `console.log(employeeData);` para imprimir en consola la respuesta del servidor. ¿No ves nada en consola? Si hay algún error de red también te lo dirá la consola. Por cierto, convendría agregar una función `error` a tu petición Ajax.

Comment: No me muestra ningun mensaje que colocastes del lado del servidor, creo que estara algo mal con mi conexion posiblemente.

Comment: @AltC verifica que esta url es correcta: `../../tec/Config/cursos.php` y revisa la consola. Allí debe decirte si la petición tiene un estatus 200, un estatus 500, un estatus 404 u otro. Sin depurar adecuadamente es imposible saber a distancia lo que está pasando. Cuando activas la consola del navegador hay varias pestañas, en una de ellas puedes ver el estado de la respuesta del servidor.

Comment: Si esta correcto la URL en ajax, en la ventana de network me muestra el status en 200

Comment: en mi archivo config tengo esto <?php

    const BASE_URL = "http://localhost/tec/";
    
    const HOST = "localhost";
    const BD = "tec";
    const DB_USER = "root";
    const PASS = "";
    const CHARSET = "charset=utf8";

?>

Comment: El código está totalmente controlado @AltC, me extraña que no veas nada en la consola.