# event.preventDefault() no está funcionando

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de que un formulario no se envie

```
<form action="~/Home/paginas" method="post" id="formSubmit">
          <button class="siguiente-imagen @ViewData["btnVolver"]" id="btnVolverPaginacion" value="@item.getNumeroEntrega()" type="submit">
                Volver
          </button>
</form>
```

Hasta hace un rato estaba funcionando pero nosé porque ahora ya no

```
$(document).ready(function () {        
    $("#formSubmit").submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
    console.log("prevent Default")

    var data = {
        'paginacion': 'siguiente',
        'entrega': $("#btnSiguientePaginacion").val()
    }
    console.log(data)

    console.log("Entra AJAX")
    $.ajax({

        url: '/Home/paginas/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
})
```

el formulario no se está frenando acá, sino que directamente va a la funcion en el controlador. "Ignora" my funcion de Javascript

Answer (score 1):

Considera cerrar tus bloques de escucha con `});`, no lo estás haciendo, ni para el bloque `$(document).ready(function() {` ni para el bloque `$("#formSubmit").submit(function(e) {`.

Aquí funciona:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#formSubmit").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Heme aquí, sin que la página se envíe');
    // rest code
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="~/Home/paginas" method="post" id="formSubmit">
  <button class="siguiente-imagen @ViewData[" btnVolver "]" id="btnVolverPaginacion" value="@item.getNumeroEntrega()" type="submit">
                Volver
          </button>
</form>
```

Si aún haciendo eso no funciona en tu contexto, entonces es porque hay otros elementos que entran en juego y eso escapa a nuestro alcance. Debes reproducir un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable que dé el mismo error aquí.

Por cierto, `$(document).ready(function() {` es obsoleto (ver la pregunta: *[jQuery 3 declaró document.ready obsoleto ¿hay cambios también para window.load?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/92628/29967)*), deberías usar `$(function() {`, por ejemplo:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#formSubmit").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Heme aquí, sin que la página se envíe');
    // rest code
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="~/Home/paginas" method="post" id="formSubmit">
  <button class="siguiente-imagen @ViewData[" btnVolver "]" id="btnVolverPaginacion" value="@item.getNumeroEntrega()" type="submit">
                Volver
          </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Es raro, hice los cambios que mencionaste, me aseguré que esté jquery y el archivo Js incluido en el HTML, y no funciona...

Comment: @BilbitBolson ¿algún error en la consola de Javascript?

Comment: No, simplemente está ignorando el `preventDefault()`  :/ Sé que lo ignora porque utilicé Loggers para saber si estaban llegando los datos al controlador y no, no están llegando

Comment: Quizá el fichero javascript ni siquiera se está ejecutando, estás seguro de que lo está cargando?

Comment: @BilbitBolson ¿qué versión de jQuery estás cargando? Verifica también lo que sugiere @PabloLozano, poniendo algo como `alert('Funciona');` en la segunda línea, justo después de `$(function() {`, verifica además que tu JS no se carga con versiones o cosas así, pues puede que estés cargando un código cacheado, no el nuevo archivo corregido.

Comment: Sisi, está funcionando ya que tengo otras funciones en el mismo archivo, como por ejemplo creo un lightbox o agrando una imagen con modal. La version de JQuery es v3.5.1